# Should I use GregorianCalendar or Date for a birthday field?

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I'm a little bit confused about using the class `GregorianCalendar` and `Date`.
What is the difference?

For instance: I have a field in a Person object that represents the date he was born.
Do I have to use `Date` or `GregorianCalendar`?

What is the best use for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were writing down the details on paper, would you write down the date of birth as a date, or would you write down a calendar with a circle around the date?

You would write down the date. [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is a concrete date. [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is a tool for working with dates.

Comment: That is not the case. Calendar was Sun's second attempt to get dates right in the Java standard libraries. Arguably, they failed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess

Answer (score 1):

I would use Date to represent the date of birth.
Use Calendar (and child classes) to manipulate dates.

Answer (score 1):

Both Date and Calendar classes suffer from poor APIs. You should use the [Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Which JodaTime class is best used for a date/time of birth?

Comment: @Freiheit It might be best to search for / ask that question separately. It depends on the context, but `LocalDate` is probably the most appropriate.