# String to date time in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a date time string "2013-06-04 23:59:59" I want to get the date and time separately from this string.

```
new Date ("2013-06-04 23:59:59")
```

constructor of java has been deprecated so I used the Calender class. I have tried the code

```
Calendar mydate = new GregorianCalendar();
        String mystring = "2013-06-04 23:59:59";
        Date thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(mystring);
        mydate.setTime(thedate);
        //breakdown
        System.out.println("mydate -> "+mydate);
        System.out.println("year   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println("month  -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println("dom    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println("dow    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        System.out.println("hour   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        System.out.println("minute -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println("second -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        System.out.println("milli  -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        System.out.println("ampm   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
        System.out.println("hod    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

but the result is wrong.

```
mydate -> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1509816960059,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=44,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_YEAR=308,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=6,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=59,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
year   -> 2017
month  -> 10
dom    -> 4
dow    -> 7
hour   -> 11
minute -> 6
second -> 0
milli  -> 59
ampm   -> 1
hod    -> 23
```

Please figure out the mistake I am doing and rectify the error.

I need the values that are mentioned in the string.

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the wrong pattern. `MM` is for month, `mm` is for minutes and `ss` for seconds.

Use:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Also, notice that the **month is zero-based**, meaning it goes from `0` to `11`, not `1` to `12`:

```
Calendar mydate = new GregorianCalendar();
String mystring = "2013-06-04 23:59:59";
Date thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(mystring);
mydate.setTime(thedate);
//breakdown
System.out.println("mydate -> "+mydate);
System.out.println("year   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("month  -> "+(mydate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)); // <-- corrected
System.out.println("dom    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("dow    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
System.out.println("hour   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR));
System.out.println("minute -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println("second -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.SECOND));
System.out.println("milli  -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
System.out.println("ampm   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
System.out.println("hod    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Comment: `SS` is for milliseconds, use `ss`

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS");
String mystring = "2013-06-04 23:59:59";
Date date  = formatter .parse(mystring);

 System.out.println("mydate -> "+date);
 System.out.println("year   -> "+date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(mystring);
```

should be

```
Date thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(mystring);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `Date` and `Calendar` are [bad design in JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and should be deprecated.Well I suggest you have a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/%E2%80%8E).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my two cents here. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is much more powerful than the built in date and time handling. It doesn't show it's full potential in an example like this but when you start doing calculations on the date it really shines.

Here is your example in Joda-Time, using the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to make the format readable and less error prone (remember the mm/MM and ss/SS mixup?)

Notice also that the month is 1 based, just as we're used to.

```
String myString = "2013-06-04 23:59:59";
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendYear(4, 4)
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .appendMonthOfYear(2)
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .appendDayOfMonth(2)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .appendHourOfDay(2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendMinuteOfHour(2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendSecondOfMinute(2)
        .toFormatter();
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(myString);

System.out.println(dateTime.year().get());
System.out.println(dateTime.monthOfYear().get());
System.out.println(dateTime.dayOfMonth().get());
System.out.println(dateTime.hourOfDay().get());
System.out.println(dateTime.minuteOfHour().get());
System.out.println(dateTime.secondOfMinute().get());
```