# How to split "yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm" format into separate date and time?

Tags: android

I am developing an app,I am using Date and time picker, To pick an date and time and I set result time 6 hours before picked time. but the result time and date shows in `yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm` this format and I want to show this date and time separately in textfields (like date is `yyyy:MM:dd` and time is `HH:mm`).How do I show this?

```
//java
public class DateTime extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
    EditText txtDate, txtTime;
    TextView dt, dt2;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
    String selected_date="",selected_time="",new_date_time="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datetime);

        btnDatePicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        btnTimePicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        txtDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_date);
        txtTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_time);
        dt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_dt);
        dt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_dt1);

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btnDatePicker) {

            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                            selected_date=year+":"+(monthOfYear + 1)+":"+dayOfMonth;
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == btnTimePicker) {

            // Get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            selected_time=hourOfDay+":"+minute;
                            setBeforeSixTime();
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);

            timePickerDialog.show();

        }

    }

    private void setBeforeSixTime() {
        try {
            Log.d("Time here ", "hiii");
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(selected_date + ":" + selected_time);
            String my_date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm");
         //   DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy:HH:mm");
            Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(my_date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -6);

            Log.d("Time here ", formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
            String s=formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
            dt.setText(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", "" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have selected_date and selected_time separately than what is the problem ?

Comment: I want to show before 6 hours from selected date n time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to date time in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996322/string-to-date-time-in-java)

Comment: I have modified your code you can check my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code as per your question i have converted your time-stamp into milliseconds and subtracted 6 hours from it and than again i converted into 6 hours previous date and time [Reference](http://androidexampleblog.blogspot.in/2016/09/android-useful-time-stamp-conversion.html)

```
try {
            Log.d("Time here ", "hiii");
            Date date;
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm");
            date = formatter.parse(selected_date + ":" + selected_time);
            //Subtracting 6 hours from selected time
            long time = date.getTime()-6*60*60*1000;

            String mDate = null;
            SimpleDateFormat formatterFullDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd");
            mDate = formatterFullDate.format(time);
            Log.e("Date ",mDate );
            String mTime = null;
            SimpleDateFormat formatterTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            mTime = formatterTime.format(time);
            Log.e("Time ",mTime );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", "" + e);
        }
```

Comment: how i convert "yyyy:MM:dd" format to "dd:MM:yyyy" format using this code

Comment: Just change this `SimpleDateFormat formatterFullDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd");` to this `SimpleDateFormat formatterFullDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy");`

Answer (score 2):

use two DateFormatter like:

```
 DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd");
 DateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 dateField.setText(dateFormatter.format(date));
 timeField.setText(timeFormatter.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it as below, you will get all as separate strings than do operations,

```
String date = "yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm";

String[] time1 = date.split(":");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
    String part3 = parts[2];
    String part3 = parts[3];
    String part4 = parts[4];
```

now, to **set values in textfield**,

```
textView1.setText(part0 + " : " + part1 + " : " + part2);

textView2.setText(part3 + " : " + part4);
```

Comment: This is so incorrect while android gives proper date objects like Calendar

Comment: my friend that is reason i have mentioned String for yyy:MM:dd:HH:mm; you must have seen that first.

Comment: if you have date in string format than this is very usefull@rohiH

Answer (score 1):

Get Date or time from on listener

```
  DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

                    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
String selectedDate=getSelectedDate(calendar.getTime());
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

// getting date from this methods

```
private String getSelectedDate(Date selectedDate){
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd");
return dateFormatter.format(selectedDate)
}
```

You can do same for time I hope this code help you

Answer (score 0):

We can split DateTime by using the below code snippet
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd,HH:mm");
    String[] time1 = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()).split(",");
    String date=time1[0];
    String time=time1[1];

Answer (score 0):

Take the complete formatted date and time in an `String` (say `strDateTime`) and then use Regular expression shown below:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}):(\\d{2}:\\d{2})").matcher(strDateTime);
if(matcher.matches()){
    textView1.setText(matcher.group(1));
    textView2.setText(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Hope this will help.