# Simplify Java Code

Tags: java, date

```
Date oDate= Entitlement_End_Date__c; //Date class from java.util

Double factor=0;

if(oDate.daysBetween(date.today())>0){
  //i.e if days between oDate and today is positive, means that oDate happened before //today's day thus meaning product is expried. 

  factor=((oDate.daysBetween(date.today())/365.00));
  if(factor>1) //greater than one year
    factor=1; // set the factor as one
  factor+=(date.today().daysBetween(TheEndDate)/365.00); //if factor is greater than //one, we want to find the exact amount of time it has expired for. 
}
else{
  factor=oDate.daysBetween(TheEndDate)/365.00;
```

I'm sure that there's an easier/simpler way of writing this that will require less lines of code? I just can't see it. Does anyone else know how to compress this into cleaner code?

Comment: I'm not totally sure this question is even on topic (maybe code review?). But either way; some text as to what this code is supposed to do would be helpful

Comment: For improving currently working code, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: use modulus division when checking for factor if you dont expect it to be grater then 2

Comment: *Always* use a pair of `{}` around `if` or `else` blocks. Use whitespace and indention.

Comment: Presumably daysBetween calculates the number of days between the one in this instance of Date and the supplied Date, and returns and integer. You call it twice for the same argument. Instead store the result in a local variable, and use the stored result for the second use.

Comment: Regarding Tichodroma's comment, indeed, the multiline-braceless-if can lead to errors later on, see http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/

Comment: Date is actually the same class as java.util.Date. 
I'll comment the code a little to help clear up any misconceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Calendar:

```
final Date endDate;
final Date startDate;


Long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime(); // calculate the difference
Date dateDiff = new Date(diff);                      // convert it to a date
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();                 // get a calendar instance
c.setTime(dateDiff);                                 // set it to the calendar
int yearDiff = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1970;            // read the year and substract the "0-year" value which is 1970
```

Dates only solution

```
final long YEAR_IN_MILLIS = 1000L*60L*60L*24L*365L;
int yearDiff = (endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime())/YEAR_IN_MILLIS;
```

And regarding java's date / calendar system: [Why is the Java date API (java.util.Date, .Calendar) such a mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess)

Comment: I'm trying to stick to using the Date class only. But thanks, this is also another route I could have taken.

Comment: @user2405875: Why? I see this from newbie programmers all the time and I don't understand the fear of using multiple classes/data types. He used a Calendar. Heaven forbid.

Comment: @user2405875 Added a Date only solution.