# What are some of the important things I need to know before Calendar API in java?

Tags: java, jodatime

The title might sound a bit generic but here are the specifics of the question

- Why exactly a lot of APIS in Date class deprecated in favor of Calendar ?
- Why using Calendar is better ? Is is computationally efficient or some other reason ?
- I currently rely on JodaTime for most of the date manipulations. Does Calendar api does something better or different than JodaTime ?

Comment: "Does Calendar api does something better than JodaTime". No. JodaTime exists only because the JDK Date/Calendar API are so horrible. Might be better with JDK8 (did not check).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess

Comment: I recommand you to continue using JodaTime, it's way much better!

Comment: @Thilo Java8 date and time objects are immutable

Comment: @Thilo Although I agree that old Calendar-API is horrible, there are indeed some things Joda-Time cannot do, for example localized week definitions (no support for US-week), but this is supported by Calendar-stuff (internationalization there is still better).

Answer (score 1):

Keep using Joda-Time or use [Java 8 - Date and Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) (which is based/inspired on Joda-Time).

Consider `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` as deprecated/obsolete.

Read [Why is the Java date API (java.util.Date, .Calendar) such a mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess?lq=1) and [Why do we need a new date and time library?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Answer (score 1):

a) Most parts of `java.util.Date` was deprecated in Java 1.1 in favor of `java.util.Calendar` because it simply lacked of timezone support.

b) `Calendar` has much more manipulations than `java.util.Date`, but for storing and formatting purposes latter one is still the only option. Remember that you cannot directly format a `Calendar`-object with `SimpleDateFormat`.

c) On most areas Joda-Time is better, for example immutability. But especially internationalization is better with old Calendar-stuff, for example localized week definition support, for some people this is a showstopper regarding Joda-Time.

d) Keep also in mind that Joda-Time is now rather an old API (for example not using enums). Some internal concepts are effectively deprecated by its own developer in favor of the new date-and-time-library in Java 8 (JSR-310, java-time-package). My prediction, Joda-Time will slowly fade out - also because it is obvious that Stephen Colebourne prefers to invest his resources in Java-8 and an extra external library called Threeten-Extra (which contains some extra calendar systems). Main remaining argument in favor of Joda-Time is still support for mixed date-and-time-periods, some simple interval-support and period formatting support.