# Fail to compare time ranges

Tags: java, time, jodatime, date-comparison

I have two `String` variables:

- `time22` will store the time generated by Linux command
- `timeInTheList`  will store the time from my `ArrayList`

`time22` will get the most current time while the `timeInTheList` will store some previous time.

I would like to compare both of these two times whether it have passed 30 minutes or not but I can't make it happen.

I found out some weird data printed out for the date, time and year and I only need the time, I will not need any date or year.

Code:

```
 for(int x = 1;x<list1.size();x+=3)
   {
    try{
         System.out.println("The time grab by linux command :"+time22);
         String timeInTheList = list1.get(x);
         System.out.println("The time in the balcklist.txt :" +timeInTheList);
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:SS"); 
         Date Ftime1 = dateFormat1.parse(timeInTheList);
         Date Stime2 = dateFormat1.parse(time22);
         System.out.println("The Ftime1 value is :" +Ftime1);
         System.out.println("The Stime2 value is :" +Stime2);
         long diff1 = Stime2.getTime() - Ftime1.getTime();
         System.out.println(Stime2.getTime());
         System.out.println(Ftime1.getTime());
         System.out.println("Difference between two time is :"+diff1);
         if(diff1 > 1800)
          {
            System.out.println("it is more than  30 minute in the list");
            String DeletedRule = list1.get(x+1).toString();
            FinalDeletion(DeletedRule);
          }
         else
          {
            System.out.println("Keep in the list first,still not reach 30 minute");
          }
        }
     catch(ParseException e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

This is the output from my program:

```
Time from linux command(In TimeIsNow Method) :22:02:50
The time grab by linux command :22:02:50
The time in the balcklist.txt :21:19:46
The Ftime1 value is :Thu Jul 01 21:00:00 MYT 1971
The Stime2 value is :Sun Feb 01 22:00:00 MYT 1970
2730600050
47223000046
Difference between two time is :-44492399996
Keep in the list first,still not reach 30 minute
```

Comment: You tagged this question with *jodatime* tag, but your code doesn't use it. Are you using (or want to use) Joda-Time?

Comment: I have the joda-time library but I not sure how to use it for this case. I use it for another purpose

Comment: @yumi Post such clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joda-Time, you can use a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the input `String` and create `LocalTime` objects - `LocalTime` seems to be the best option, as you're dealing only with time (hour/minute/second) and don't need to know the date (day/month/year).

Having the `LocalTime` objects, you can use the `Minutes` class to get the minutes between them:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.Minutes;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String time22 = "22:02:50";
String timeInTheList = "21:19:46";

// create formatter with format hour:minute:second
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");

// parse Strings
LocalTime sTime2 = fmt.parseLocalTime(time22);
LocalTime fTime1 = fmt.parseLocalTime(timeInTheList);

// get the minutes between them
int minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(fTime1, sTime2).getMinutes();
System.out.println(minutes); // 43
```

The code above will output `43` (the number of minutes between `21:19:46` and `22:02:50`).

As the inputs are in a [standard ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) (`HH:mm:ss`), you can also parse them without a formatter:

```
LocalTime sTime2 = LocalTime.parse(time22);
LocalTime fTime1 = LocalTime.parse(timeInTheList);
```

---

## Java new Date/Time API

Joda-Time is being discontinued and replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with joda. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.

So, if you don't have a huge codebase in Joda-Time (which would require a lot of work to migrate) or if you want to use the new API's, check how to use it below.

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The code is very similar to Joda's:

```
// if you're using ThreeTen Backport, replace java.time by org.threeten.bp
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

String time22 = "22:02:50";
String timeInTheList = "21:19:46";

// parse Strings
LocalTime sTime2 = LocalTime.parse(time22);
LocalTime fTime1 = LocalTime.parse(timeInTheList);

// get the minutes between them
long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(fTime1, sTime2);
System.out.println(minutes); // 43
```

The output is the same (43 minutes).

---

**Notes:**

In your original code, there are 2 problems:

- The format is wrong: `MM` is the month, and `SS` is the fraction of second (check [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details). That's why you're getting unexpected results when parsing:

  - when parsing `22:02:50`, it takes `02` as the month (so it becomes February). All the missing fields are set to default values (day is 1, year is 1970, minutes is 0 and so on)
  - when parsing `21:19:46`, it takes `19` as the month. So the parser takes the default value for year (1970) and take the 19<sup>th</sup> month from it (considering that January of 1970 is the first month, the 19<sup>th</sup> month is July of 1971)
- The `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`, so you're getting the difference in milliseconds (you'd need to convert it to minutes).

Anyway, using Joda-Time (or the new Date/Time API) make things much easier and I don't recommend using the old `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Comment: it's working as expected,cheer for you, let me learn new things

Comment: the Java 8 method working but joda-time have some compatible issue with others library, since I am using java 8,so I just use the java 8 method

Comment: @yumi Good! Much better to use the new API! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, you can use **New Date/Time API**.
Please try below code:

```
// Required imports
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Duration;

// Taken hard-coded values for testing purpose
String time22 = "22:02:50", timeInTheList = "21:19:46";

LocalTime Stime2 = LocalTime.parse(time22);
LocalTime Ftime1 = LocalTime.parse(timeInTheList);

System.out.println("Stime2: " + Stime2);
System.out.println("Ftime1: " + Ftime1);

Duration duration = Duration.between(Ftime1, Stime2);
long diff1 = duration.getSeconds();
System.out.println("duration: " + diff1);

if(diff1 > 1800){
  System.out.println("it is more than 30 minute in the list");
  /**
   * Your remaining code goes here.
   */
}else{
  System.out.println("Keep in the list first, still not reach 30 minute");
}
```

Comment: You could also use `duration.toMinutes()` instead of `getSeconds()`

Comment: Yes, definitely. But in the code posted by yumi in the question, there was a comparison of seconds, so I used getSeconds() method.