# What type to use for a Java 8 bean date property - Instant or ZoneDateTime?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I'm picking up on Java programming after a couple of years away. I've noticed that with Java 8 there are some new date/time objects.

For a persisted data bean using Java 8 what type should I use for a date/time property?  Is it `Instant`, `ZoneDateTime` or `Date`?

Comment: If you need to know the time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`. If you only need the point in time, `Instant` is preferred. As you probably know, you can always convert it to `ZonedDateTime` to display it to a user in some time zone.

Comment: If there’s any way you can avoid the long outdated `Date` class, you will want to. I gather there is. `Instant` is generally considered the modern replacement for it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid the old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`). They have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and most of them were fixed by the new API (that's why the new classes were created, BTW).

---

IMO, it's always better to work internally with date/time objects in **UTC** - and the best class for that is `Instant`, which is always in UTC. So, to persist in a database and do internal operations, I always prefer to work with UTC date/time, as it makes things less confusing and avoids unnecessary convertions all the time.

**When/if** you need to display this date/time - to an user, or in some other interface - and you want it to be in a specific timezone, then you convert this `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime`.

Example:

```
// create current instant in UTC - Instant is **always** in UTC
Instant now = Instant.now();
System.out.println(now); // 2017-06-20T13:28:39.075Z

// converting to some timezone
ZonedDateTime z = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(z); // 2017-06-20T10:28:39.075-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

// converting to another timezone
z = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(z); // 2017-06-20T14:28:39.075+01:00[Europe/London]

// converting back to Instant
System.out.println(z.toInstant()); // 2017-06-20T13:28:39.075Z
```

So, the UTC instant is `2017-06-20T13:28:39.075Z`, which corresponds to `2017-06-20T10:28:39.075-03:00` in São Paulo and `2017-06-20T14:28:39.075+01:00` in London (note that the `ZoneId` already takes care of Daylight Saving changes).

Also note that I used the full timezone names (`America/Sao_Paulo` and `Europe/London`). These names in the format `Continent/City` are defined by the [IANA database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and are used by the new API.

You should avoid the use of 3-letter timezones names (like `ECT` or `CST`), because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). Always prefer to use the full names - you can get all the available names by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` - this will get the default timezone configured in your system. But this can be changed in runtime, leading to unpredictable results, so it's always better to use an explicit timezone.

---

The output above is the result of the `toString()` method of each object. But if you want a different format, you can use the `DateTimeFormatter` class:

```
ZonedDateTime z = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss xxx");
System.out.println(fmt.format(z)); // 20/06/2017 10:28:39 -03:00
```

Please refer to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see all possible formats.

Comment: Many thanks for the considered answer.  One further related question on how to relate timestamps back to the timezone of the originating agent.  Assume that I have a system that takes orders, and I want to store the timestamp of the order using 'Instant', how best to record the time zone of the agent that placed the order?  In otherwords, were they in Sao Paulo or London?

Comment: If that is a requirement, @user2868835, either store a `ZoneId` too (`ZoneId.systemDefault()` will give you the JVM’s setting) or make an exception and store a `ZonedDateTime` instead of the `Instant`, this will give you both, and you can still always convert according to needs.

Comment: IMO, it's better to work internally with `Instant` and store the `ZoneId` in a separate field (so you use it (`atZone(zoneid)`) just when displaying the date to the user).

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the property in the bean to be `Instant` as it is in UTC, wherever it needs to be presented to the client, it could be converted to the appropriate `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // gives current instant of time in UTC. 

//Can be converted to ZonedDateTime
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zone ) ;
```