# Convert string to date (CEST works fine, GMT+02:00 doesn't work)

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-parsing

## Question

Why is my Android app unable to parse `String str1= "Tue Jun 20 15:56:29 CEST 2017"`?

I found some similar questions, but none of them helped me.

### Sidenotes

In my project I have some Java applications which are running on a computer and some Android applications. They are able to communicate to each other.

In the messages are timestamps. However my Java applications are sending timestamps in a format like `String str1= "Tue Jun 20 15:56:29 CEST 2017"` and my Android apps like `String str2 = "Tue Jun 20 13:40:37 GMT+02:00 2017"`. To save the message including the time I have to parse the incoming time to a date.

## My Android-App

In my Android app I can't parse the `String str1= "Tue Jun 20 15:56:29 CEST 2017"` correctly:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jun 20 15:56:29 CEST 2017"

`String str2 = "Tue Jun 20 13:40:37 GMT+02:00 2017"`is working fine.

### Code:

```
    String str1 = "Tue Jun 20 14:53:08 CEST 2017";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(str1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // test
    String str2 = "Tue Jun 20 13:40:37 GMT+02:00 2017";
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(str2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## My Java-App

However, my Java application can parse both strings correctly.

### Code:

```
    String str = "Tue Jun 20 14:53:08 CEST 2017";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // test
    str = "Tue Jun 20 13:40:37 GMT+02:00 2017";
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## ThreeTen Solution

### String to LocalDateTime

To convert my incoming string I'm using the following code:

```
    String time = "Mon Jun 26 15:42:51 GMT 2017";
    DateTimeFormatter gmtDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));
    LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(time, gmtDateTimeFormatter);
```

### LocalDateTime to String

To convert my LocalDateTime to a string I used this:

```
    LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter gmtDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));
    String time = gmtDateTimeFormatter.format(timestamp);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). For Android, see the ThreeTen-Backport project.

Comment: It would really be best if you could get a string that doesn’t include a four letter time zone abbreviation. The three and four letter abbreviations are generally ambiguous and sometimes — as with CEST — only half time zones. For CEST I wouldn’t know what result to expect if the date was in winter where CEST isn’t used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a difference on how Android handles the `zzzz` pattern (probably Java's implementation handles it better than Android, so it "guesses" the correct timezone in a way that Android doesn't). I don't know.

Anyway, may I suggest you to avoid using those old classes? These old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To parse both formats, you can use a `DateTimeFormatter` with optional sections. That's because `CEST` is a timezone short name and `GMT+02:00` is an UTC offset, so if you want to parse both with the same formatter, you'll need to use one optional section for each format.

Another detail is that short names like `CET` or `CEST` are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). The new API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).

So, you need to choose one timezone that suits your needs. In the example below, I've just picked a timezone that's in CEST (`Europe/Berlin`), but you can change it according to what you need - you can get a list of all names using `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

As the new API doesn't resolve `CEST` (because of its ambiguity), I need to create a set with the prefered timezone in order to correctly parse the input:

```
// when parsing, if finds ambiguous CET or CEST, it uses Berlin as prefered timezone
Set<ZoneId> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // your pattern (weekday, month, day, hour/minute/second)
    .appendPattern("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
    // optional timezone short name (like "CST" or "CEST")
    .optionalStart().appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, set).optionalEnd()
    // optional GMT offset (like "GMT+02:00")
    .optionalStart().appendPattern("OOOO").optionalEnd()
    // year
    .appendPattern(" yyyy")
    // create formatter (using English locale to make sure it parses weekday and month names correctly)
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);
```

To parse `Tue Jun 20 14:53:08 CEST 2017`, just use the formatter:

```
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue Jun 20 14:53:08 CEST 2017", fmt);
System.out.println(z1);
```

The output is:

> 2017-06-20T14:53:08+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

Note that `CEST` was mapped to `Europe/Berlin`, according to the set we created.

To parse `Tue Jun 20 13:40:37 GMT+02:00 2017`, we can use the same formatter. But `GMT+02:00` can be in a lot of different regions, so the API can't map it to a single timezone. To convert it to the correct timezone, I need to use `withZoneSameInstant()` method:

```
// parse with UTC offset
ZonedDateTime z2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue Jun 20 13:40:37 GMT+02:00 2017", fmt)
    // convert to Berlin timezone
    .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
System.out.println(z2);
```

The output is:

> 2017-06-20T13:40:37+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

---

**PS:** the first case (`z1`) works in Java 8, but in ThreeTen Backport it's not setting the timezone to Berlin. To fix it, just call `.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))` as we did with `z2`.

---

If you still need to use `java.util.Date`, you can convert from and to the new API.

In `java.time`, new methods were added to `Date` class:

```
// convert ZonedDateTime to Date
Date date = Date.from(z1.toInstant());

// convert back to ZonedDateTime (using Berlin timezone)
ZonedDateTime z = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
```

In ThreeTen backport (and Android), you can use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
// convert ZonedDateTime to Date
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(z1.toInstant());

// convert back to ZonedDateTime (using Berlin timezone)
ZonedDateTime z = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So far I implemented in my Android-App ThreeTenABP and in my Java-App ThreeTen. Now there are still small problems.

Comment: The Android-App print the date with an dot and the Java-App not. However, I guess there is no easy solution. I have to work with regular expressions and build my own string.

Comment: Do you mean a dot after the seconds? In my examples I call `println` with the date object (which calls `toString` and it prints the fraction of seconds). If you want to change the output format, use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: No the dot appears behind the day. But only in the Android-App. (See my edited Question -> new problems)

Comment: You're creating a formatter without a locale, so it uses the JVM's default. Try to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)` instead (or `Locale.US`, probably both will work).

Comment: That's the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Do not use a fixed text for the timezone:

Do not use a fixed text (e.g. `'GMT'`) for the timezone as you have done because that approach may fail for other locales.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(parse("Tue Jun 20 14:53:08 CEST 2017"));
        System.out.println(parse("Tue Jun 20 13:40:37 GMT+02:00 2017"));
    }

    static ZonedDateTime parse(String strDateTime) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s z u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-06-20T14:53:08+02:00[Europe/Paris]
2017-06-20T13:40:37+02:00[GMT+02:00]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/oTaymI)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>