# getDisplayNames from Calendar gives months unsorted

Tags: java, calendar

I am getting successfully the months from `Calendar` like this:

```
monthMap = calendar.getDisplayNames(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

But the months appear like:

[image]

Is there anyway I will get them as January 1st with index 0 and then the rest?

I would sort the list but there is no criteria for the sort.

Any ideas?

Comment: `getDisplayNames` returns a `Map`; I'd guess it's a `HashMap`, and thus has no defined ordering.

Comment: yes it is a hashmap and my question is how to sort the keyset which is what is displayed in the pic

Comment: `monthMap.entrySet().sorted(/* your criteria */).collect(...)`.

Comment: and what is the criteria? How to sort the months?

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a map completely unsorted, so you need to implement a sort criteria by the values

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = Calendar.getInstance().getDisplayNames(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG,
            Locale.getDefault());
 List<Entry<String, Integer>> months = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
 months.sort((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue()));
 months.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

OR you can consider using the `java.time` power since **java8**, because we all should stop learning the old bad/evil/broken java Calendar:

```
Month month = Month.JUNE;

for (Month m : Month.values()) {
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

or to keep coherence to java8

```
Arrays.stream(Month.values()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: that is indeed a correct answer but not the answer to my question!!

Comment: @KostasDrakonakis, in this case, can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd recommend to stop using `Calendar` (as already suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44657644/7605325)).

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

For me it's not clear if you want a list with the month names or a map with the months in order (having the month name as key and the number as value). Anyway, here's a code for both (assuming that the default locale is English):

```
// created the sorted list
List<String> months = new ArrayList<>();
for (Month m : Month.values()) {
    months.add(m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()));
}
System.out.println("list: " + months);

// create the map (using LinkedHashMap, as it preserves the insertion order)
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
int i = 0;
for (String m : months) {
    map.put(m, i++);
}
System.out.println("map: " + map);
```

The output will be:

> list: [January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December]
>
> map: {January=0, February=1, March=2, April=3, May=4, June=5, July=6, August=7, September=8, October=9, November=10, December=11}

Comment: Good Answer. I would emphasize more the direct use of the `Month` enum objects directly. I suspect the original poster is using Strings to track the months as entities for more work rather than just the name of the month for presentation. With a proper understanding of enum objects, the OP can learn to pass around `Month` objects as arguments rather than strings, and can learn to use the enum objects as keys in maps or items in lists, and as values in member variables on classes. In other words, use `Month` everywhere with the only month-related string being generated for presentation to user.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find a way to sort it. Chances are you're getting back a HashMap, which doesn't promise any order.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Calendar.getInstance()
    .getDisplayNames(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());

List<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = 
    new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet()); 

//This line sorts entries by key.
Collections.sort(entries, 
    (entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey()));

//Now the list will be sorted:
for(Entry<String, Integer> entry: entries) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

For numeric sort, you can replace the call to `sort` with

```
Collections.sort(entries, 
    (entry1, entry2) -> Integer.valueOf(entry1.getKey()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(entry2.getKey())));
```

Comment: With this they'll be sorted, but alphabetically.

Comment: thanks for the try. I created my own hashMap with getting items from DateFormatSymbols which returns the items with the method: [getMonths()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getMonths())