# Calendar : don't allow past timestamp

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar

I'm scheduling a repeating alarm, ringing every Tuesday morning, at 08:30.

Because of Doze, I can't use `AlarmManager.setRepeating` because the time of the alarm won't be precise (it needs to be, I understand the effects on battery).

So, I use this code to schedule the first alarm :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.WEDNESDAY); // Trick not to get a "tuesday" timestamp in the past if today is wednesday+ !
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long scheduledTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduledTime, pendingIntent);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduledTime, pendingIntent);
} else {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduledTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

And it works flawlessly.

Problem is, I have to re-schedule the alarm when the `Intent` in consumed by my `BroadcastReceiver`, on Tuesday, 8:30AM.

But between Tuesday 08:30 and Tuesday 23:59, the method will give me a timestamp in the "past", which is incorrect.

Is there any method than "if the provided timestamp is in the past, add 1 week to it" to fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why you can't calculate the next scheduling date/time when rescheduling the alarm.

Comment: Because the first part of the code (line 0 - 8) will give me a timestamp that is before now ?

Comment: Compare `if (calculated.before(now)) {...`

Comment: @LewBloch That's what I'm doing at the moment, but it feels so inelegant, I'm looking for a more "generic" approach.

Comment: "Feels" is an emotion. What is the engineering rationale? Anyway, you're already setting the initial value of `calendar` to the current time twice, which is "inelegant" by engineering standards. You might consider using the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int- method if you are sticking with the old-fashioned time manipulation library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes, together with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

*Although you can also use Joda-Time, it's in maintainance mode and being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.*

All the classes below are under the package `org.threeten.bp`.

---

First of all, I've checked the documentation of `AlarmManager` and it seems to work with timestamps (the `long` parameter in `set` methods), which is the number of milliseconds from `1970-01-01T00:00Z`.

So, you need a `ZonedDateTime` (a date and time in a specific timezone), because you need to know the date, time and the timezone to get a specific timestamp millis:

```
import org.threeten.bp.DayOfWeek;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalTime;
import org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

// current date/time at system's default timezone
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();

// get next Tuesday at 08:30 AM
ZonedDateTime nextTuesday = now
    // get the next Tuesday
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY))
    // at 08:30 AM
    .with(LocalTime.of(8, 30));
System.out.println(nextTuesday);

// get the millis timestamp
long scheduledTime = nextTuesday.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

The `TemporalAdjusters.next()` method does the trick of finding the next Tuesday. If the current date is already a Tuesday and you don't want to get the Tuesday of next week, you can replace it by `TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame()`.

The `LocalTime.of(8, 30)` sets the hour to 08:30 AM (it already sets the **seconds** and **milliseconds** to zero).

---

The code above gets the current date/time using the system's default timezone (probably the one configured in the device). If you want a specific timezone, you can use the `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` or `org.threeten.bp.ZoneOffset` classes:

```
// current date/time at London
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

// current date/time in UTC
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/London`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

---

If you already have a `java.util.Calendar`, you can convert from and to the new API using the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
// convert calendar to ZonedDateTime, using system's default timezone
ZonedDateTime z = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(calendar).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

// convert back to calendar
Calendar c = DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(z);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest going for the new `java.time` API for this calculation. The [ThreeTenABP project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) is an adaptation of that library for Android specifically.

Here is an example of getting 08:30 AM of every Tuesday using `java.time` API:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
now.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY))
   .withHour(8)
   .withMinute(30)
   .withSecond(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate next Tuesday's 8:30 am with this code.
It uses JodaTime Library.

At the time of this answer this is the dependancy to add to build.gradle:  `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'`

```
public DateTime getNextTuesday830(DateTime now){
        DateTime rtn = now;

        int thisDay = now.getDayOfWeek();
        int deltaNexTuesday = -1;

        if(thisDay >= DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY){
            deltaNexTuesday =  DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY + 7 - thisDay;
        }else{
            deltaNexTuesday = DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY - thisDay;
        }

        rtn = rtn.plusDays(deltaNexTuesday).withHourOfDay(8).withMinuteOfHour(30).withSecondOfMinute(0);

        return rtn;
    }
```

To calculate the *now* parameter:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

To get back a Date() object from DateTime:

```
Date d = now.toDate();
```

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes. See the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thx, I wasn't aware of that.