# Setting and formatting time zone with Calendar object in Java and then returning a Date object

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timezone

I have a function where I need to grab the current date, set to another time zone, and return that converted/formatted date as a `Date` object.  I have code that works, however, the `Date` object does not set to the newly converted date, it returns the current date.

Here is the code:

```
public static Date getCurrentLocalDateTime() {

    Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    TimeZone obj = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Denver");
    formatter.setTimeZone(obj);

    Logger.info("Local:: " + currentdate.getTime());

    String formattedDate = formatter.format(currentdate.getTime());

    Logger.info("America/Denver:: "+ formattedDate);

    Date finalDate = null;
    try {
        finalDate = formatter.parse(formattedDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Logger.info("finalDate:: " + finalDate);

    return finalDate;
}
```

From the examples I have reviewed and tried, this should work correctly.  One of the issues is that I need to return the `Date` object so it works with the current code.

The output looks like:

```
2017-07-03 17:08:24,499 [INFO] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 -
                Local:: Mon Jul 03 17:08:24 UTC 2017
2017-07-03 17:08:24,501 [INFO] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 -
                America/Denver:: 2017-07-03 11:08:24
2017-07-03 17:08:24,502 [INFO] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 -
                finalDate:: Mon Jul 03 17:08:24 UTC 2017
```

As you can see, it formats the date correctly to the Mountain Time Zone, but then sets it back to the `Calendar` time.

---

EDIT --- Code solution:

```
public static Date getCurrentLocalDateTime() {
    Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    ZonedDateTime converted = currentdate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Denver"))
            .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Date finalDate = Date.from(converted.toInstant());
    return finalDate;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect a different result?

Comment: I expect the date returned to, based on the log output above, to be `Mon Jul 03 11:08:24 UTC 2017` not `Mon Jul 03 17:08:24 UTC 2017` - since I formatted the Calendar object to Mountain Time.

Comment: IMHO some have not done their requirement specification right. In 2017 you should not be required to return an instance of the long outdated `Date` class. The Java date and time API (since Java 8, backported to Java 6 and 7) are so much better and nicer to work with, for you and for whoever receives your return value. And if you could return a `ZonedDateTime` object, it would have a time zone of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` object [**has no timezone information**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/). It has only a `long` value, which is the number of milliseconds from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` (also known as *"unix epoch"* or just *"epoch"*). This value is absolutely independent of timezone (you can say "it's in UTC" as well).

When you call `Logger.info("finalDate:: " + finalDate);`, it calls the `toString()` method of `java.util.Date`, and this method uses the system's default timezone behind the scenes, giving the impression that the date object itself has a timezone - **but it doesn't**.

Check the values of `finalDate.getTime()` and `currentdate.getTimeInMillis()`, you'll see they are **almost** the same - "almost" because the `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't have the **fraction of seconds**, so you're losing the milliseconds precision (`format` method creates a `String` without the milliseconds, and the `parse` method sets it to zero when the field is not present). If I change the formatter to this, though:

```
// using ".SSS" to don't lose milliseconds when formatting
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

The output is:

> Local:: Mon Jul 03 17:34:34 UTC 2017
>   America/Denver:: 2017-07-03 11:34:34.508
>   finalDate:: Mon Jul 03 17:34:34 UTC 2017

And both `finalDate.getTime()` and `currentdate.getTimeInMillis()` will have exactly the same values (Note that `Date.toString()` doesn't print the milliseconds, so you can't know what's their value - only by comparing `getTime()` values you know if they are the same).

Conclusion: just change your formatter to use the milliseconds (`.SSS`) and parsing/formatting will work. The fact that it shows the dates in another timezone is an implementation detail (`toString()` method uses system's default timezone), but the milliseconds value is correct.

If you want to get 11h at UTC, you must create another formatter and set its timezone to UTC:

```
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
finalDate = parser.parse(formattedDate);
```

Then, `finalDate`'s time will have the value of 11h at UTC:

> finalDate:: Mon Jul 03 11:34:34 UTC 2017

---

## New Java Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To do what you need, you can use a `ZonedDateTime` (a date and time + a timezone) and convert to another timezone keeping the same date/time values:

```
// current date/time in Denver
ZonedDateTime denverNow = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Denver"));
// convert to UTC, but keeping the same date/time values (like 11:34)
ZonedDateTime converted = denverNow.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(converted); // 2017-07-03T11:34:34.508Z
```

The output will be:

> 2017-07-03T11:34:34.508Z

If you want a different format, use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // pattern for day/hour
    .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
    // UTC offset
    .appendOffset("+HHMM", "UTC")
    // year
    .appendPattern(" yyyy")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(fmt.format(converted));
```

The output will be:

> Mon Jul 03 11:34:34 UTC 2017

---

If you still need to use `java.util.Date`, you can easily convert from/to the new API.

In Java >= 8:

```
// convert your Calendar object to ZonedDateTime
converted = currentdate.toInstant()
               .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Denver"))
               .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// converted is equals to 2017-07-03T11:34:34.508Z

// from ZonedDateTime to Date and Calendar (date will be 11:34 UTC)
Date d = Date.from(converted.toInstant());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);

// to get a Date that corresponds to 11:34 in Denver
Date d = Date.from(converted.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/Denver")).toInstant());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);
```

In Java <= 7 (ThreeTen Backport), you can use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
// convert Calendar to ZonedDateTime 
converted = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(currentdate)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Denver"))
                .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// converted is equals to 2017-07-03T11:34:34.508Z

// convert ZonedDateTime to Date (date will be 11:34 UTC)
Date d = DateTimeUtils.toDate(converted.toInstant());
Calendar c = DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(converted);

// to get a Date that corresponds to 11:34 in Denver
Date d = DateTimeUtils.toDate(converted.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/Denver")).toInstant());
Calendar c = DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(converted.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/Denver")));
```

Comment: Thank you - will this return the Date object of `Mon Jul 03 11:34:34 UTC 2017`?  I need the time to be 11:00 AM, not 5:00 PM (17:00).

Comment: The Date object contains the value that corresponds to 11:34 in **America/Denver** (which is equivalent to 17:34 in UTC). If you want a `String` with 11:34, use a formatter with Denver timezone set (like the one you're already using). Or do you really want "11:34 UTC"?

Comment: I want to have the 11:34 UTC returned if possible.

Comment: @Dan I've updated the answer with 2 alternatives: using `SimpleDateFormat` or using the new date/time API - if this new API is available to you, I recommend using it, as it's much better and easier (and IMO, much more clear about what it's doing, like the method `withZoneSameLocal`, that does the conversion directly, without the need to format and parse in obscure ways)

Comment: thanks for updating the example.  I would like to use the ZonedDateTime example.  Is there a way to convert the `converted` object the into a Date object?  Or will this just set it back to UTC value, not the Denver time zone?

Comment: @Dan  You can convert a `ZonedDateTime` to `Date` in both UTC or Denver. I've updated the answer with this info

Comment: worked perfectly!  I have updated my post with the code.