# How to get last quarter details using java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have achieved getting the previous quarter like as shown below:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int presentQuarter = (month / 3) + 1;
int lastQuarter = (presentQuarter - 1) > 0 ? presentQuarter - 1 : 4;
```

I have got the `lastQuarter` but how I will get the last quarter's year.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque do you think those legacy classes gives me wrong values

Comment: It's not the case of wrong values, but how difficult it is to work with the legacy vs the new API, which make things much easier (and of course, doing the math by yourself instead of letting the API does it for you is much more error prone). Not to mention the [tons of well known problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) of the old API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your own condition for that too,

```
year = (presentQuarter - 1) > 0 ? year:year-1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a separate variable for storing your quarter calculation.  I would try something like the following.

```
int calculatedLastQuarter = presentQuarter - 1;
int lastQuarterYear = (calculatedLastQuater < 0) ? year-1 : year;
int lastQuarter = (presentQuarter < 0) ? 4 : calculatedLastQuater;
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you can do the math by yourself (as the other answers are already covering), you could consider using the new date/time API.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The code is straightforward:

```
// current date
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

// get quarter
int presentQuarter = now.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);

// year for last quarter
int year = now.minus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS).getYear();
```

`LocalDate` is in `java.time` or `org.threeten.bp` package, and `IsoFields` is in `java.time.temporal` or `org.threeten.bp.temporal` (depending on whether you're using Java 8 or ThreeTen Backport).

---

I'm using `LocalDate.now()`, which gets the current date using the system's default timezone, but it's better to always make explicit what timezone you're using (even it you use the default):

```
// use system default timezone
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

But the system's default timezone can change (even at runtime), so it's even better to explicit one by name:

```
// current date using an explicit timezone name
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> how I will get the last quarter's year.

```
YearQuarter.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ) 
           .minusQuarters( 1 )
           .getYear()
```

> 2017

## `YearQuarter`

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project adds functionality to the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

Among the project’s classes are `Quarter` and [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html). These quarters are based on the ISO 8601 calendar, running January-March and so on.

Get current quarter.

```
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
```

Call `minusQuarters` to do math.

```
YearQuarter yqPrevious = yq.minusQuarters( 1 ) ;
```

If needed, you can extract the year and quarter numbers. Better to pass these YearQuarter objects around your code base than to use mere ints, to gain type-safety and endure valid values.

```
int year = yqPrevious.getYear() ;
int q = yqPrevious.getQuarterValue() ;
```

To serialize to a string, call `toString` to generate a string in a format that follows the style of the ISO 8601 formats: yyyy-Qq (though that standard does not actually address quarters).

```
String output = yq.toString() ;
```

…and parsing…

```
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.parse( "2017-Q1" ) ;
```