# SimpleDateFormat how to set a format only contain weekday name, hour and minutes?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

1.Now I was trying to create a SimpleDateFormat that only contain weekday name, hour and minutes.
I just defined a schema like this: DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE:hh:mm"); However, it seems like this pattern did not work at all;

2.Here is my code to define a date format, the code below can only contain hours and minutes, When I try to input "Tue:21:30", "Tue" will not be stored. How can defined a time format just like ""Tue 21:30""?

```
             DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE:hh:mm");
          
             Date date = sdf.parse("Tue:21:30");
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             cal.setTime(date);
             int hours = 8;
             int minutes =3000;
             cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
             cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
             date = cal.getTime();
             System.out.println(date);
             System.out.println(date.getDay());
             System.out.println(date.getHours())
```

Comment: Can't you use the newer `DateTimeFormatter` instead? Also, what do you mean by "Tue:21:30"? Is that the coming Tuesday or the previous Tuesday or the Tuesday that is in this week?

Comment: I mean the date should only contain weekday name,hour, and minutes. The format"Tue:21:30"，please just ignore it. The format does not matter, as long as the time contain n weekday name,hour, and minutes.

Comment: `hh` is "12 hour hour-of-day value", i.e. 01-12. For 21, you'd need `HH`. (But I would very strongly recommend using java.time instead.)

Answer (score 2):

The `java.util.Date` class represents the combination of a date with with a time-of-day as seen in UTC.

You have only a day-of-week, not a date. And you have no indicator of offset or time zone. You have only one of the pieces needed, a time-of-day. So it makes no sense to parse a string such as `"Tue:21:30"`.

Another thing: You are using terrible date-time classes. These classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To pair a day-of-week with a time-of-day, write a class. In Java 16, I would use the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature to briefly write such a class. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record DayOfWeekTime ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek , LocalTime localTime ) {}
```

Usage.

```
DayOfWeekTime dowTime = new DayOfWeekTime( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , LocalTime.of( 21 , 30 ) ) ;
```

Or use a pair of `int` values for hour and minute instead of `LocalTime` if you want to restrict the data that way. I would add an explicit constructor too, to validate the range of allowed values on those `int` inputs.

```
record DayOfWeekTime ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek , int hour , int minute ) {}
```

Add methods to parse and generate strings in your desired format.

You might want to add a `compareTo` method to implement the `Comparable` interface, if you need sorting.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can a create a Data which just only contain  weekday name, hour and minutes?

Comment: @JayParkkk You can’t.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` represents an instant in time. "9:30 pm on Tuesday" is not an instant in time - *which* Tuesday do you mean? 9:30 pm in what timezone? You can assume default values for these things if you use `DateTimeFormatter`, but from the comments it seems like you don't want to assume anything. You just want to store what is parsed.

You can write your own class that represents a day-of-week + hour + minutes *only*. If you implement `TemporalAccessor`, you will be able to parse and format it with `DateTimeFormatter`. Here is an example:

```
final class DayOfWeekLocalTime implements TemporalAccessor {

  private final DayOfWeek dow;
  private final int hour;
  private final int minute;

  private DayOfWeekLocalTime(DayOfWeek dow, int hour, int minute) {
    this.dow = dow;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
  }

  public static DayOfWeekLocalTime of(DayOfWeek dow, int hour, int minute) {
    return new DayOfWeekLocalTime(dow, hour, minute);
  }

  public static DayOfWeekLocalTime parse(String s, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parse(s);
    return new DayOfWeekLocalTime(
        DayOfWeek.of(ta.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
        ta.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        ta.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR)
    );
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // a default format
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE:HH:mm").format(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isSupported(TemporalField field) {
    return field == ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK ||
        field.getBaseUnit() == ChronoUnit.HOURS ||
        field.getBaseUnit() == ChronoUnit.MINUTES ||
        field == ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY;
  }

  @Override
  public long getLong(TemporalField field) {
    if (!isSupported(field)) {
      throw new UnsupportedTemporalTypeException("Unsupported field: " + field);
    }
    if (field == ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK) {
      return dow.getValue();
    }
    return field.getFrom(LocalTime.of(hour, minute));
  }

  // equals and hashcode omitted for brevity
}
```

To parse it:

```
DayOfWeekLocalTime.parse("Tue:21:30", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE:HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Do not use](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.util.date`, as it has several negative aspects.

Use newer (since Java 8) [JSR 310: Date Time API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You can do:

```java
DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE HH:mm");
DateTimeFormatter format2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE HH:mm"); //gives you full name of the day

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();

//if it's Thursday, 10:30
System.out.println(ldt.format(format1)); //prints Thu 10:30
System.out.println(ldt.format(format2)); //prints Thursday 10:30
```

Alternatively, use any other date object instead of `.now()` from the [`LocalDateTime API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

<sup>Some other references on why not to use `java.util.date` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033459/1553537), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730136/should-i-use-java-util-date-or-switch-to-java-time-localdate), [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/5-reasons-why-javas-old-date-and-Calendar-API-bad.html), and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro).</sup>