# Read two dates from jsf page and search only files with that dated using

Tags: java, file, timestamp

I have files that end with unix timestamp such:

```
Product.txt.1500256801
Product.txt.1500260400
Product.txt.1500264001
Product.txt.1500267601
...
```

In 5 days the files will be to 120 files
For exm: I want to search any word in the files but not all 5 days only 3 days
From `2017-07-05`
To `2017-07-08`
These two date and the word i search for entered by jsf page
The problem not jsf page or how to find word in files 
The real problem when take that `fromDate` and `toDate` how only i limited the search on that date (for acknowledgment: in these 3 days i will have 72 files, i want to search 72 files not all 124 files)

I tried this idea:
Read all timestamp to list of string

```
for(int i=0; i<listOfExt; i++)
{
stringList = listOfExt.get(i).replaceAll(regex,"$1");
}
lista1.add(stringList);//where. I get only from files name the suffix 1500256801,1500260400, and so on ...
```

I then create two new lists (lista2 and lista3)
And read the two dates entered by jsf page to two string then i compare

```
if(lista1.contains(fromDate)&&lista1.contains(toDate))
{
lista2 = lista1.subList(lista1.indexOf(startDate),lista1.indexOf(endDate)+1);
lista3.add(lista2.toString);
}
else
{
//some thing such: the user entered date not created its file to now
}
```

Comment: I don't see any jsf here...

Comment: If you know the issue is with the JSF page and its controller, why don't you show us the code of those? Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Note that the problem not from jsf page as i successfully implemented that .

Comment: In my managed bean i receive the two date without problem and until i can convert them to timestamp

Comment: I want to solve the problem even without jsf page.

Comment: How are these timestamps created? When you search from 2017-07-05 to 2017-07-08, are you considering that the dates are in what timezone (or in UTC)?

Comment: First i convert them from date to time stamp so i can compare them with suffix timestamp of files but not success.

Comment: Hi @Hugo, second i tried to read the fromDate and  toDate and the suffix of file  as date and convert them to string to compare.

Comment: Time zone that files written is GMT +03:00 is Asia/Baghdad (AST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the new Date/Time API, because the old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, there's the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), which comes natively within the JDK.

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

---

As I understood, your files are generated hourly. I took the timestamps and found that they correspond to the following dates (in UTC):

> 2017-07-17T02:00:01Z
>   2017-07-17T03:00:00Z
>   2017-07-17T04:00:01Z
>   2017-07-17T05:00:01Z

I suppose that it's a scheduled job that does it, and note that sometimes it takes 1 second to generate it (giving hours like `05:00:01`). But as the files are generated hourly, **I believe we can discard the seconds**.

First, we need to get the start and end dates, and I'm assuming they come as strings in the format `2017-07-05` - that's how you specified in the question.

I'm also assuming that these dates correspond to UTC (but we can change the code if it's not, more on that below):

```
// start date (set the time to start of day)
ZonedDateTime from = LocalDate.parse("2017-07-05").atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// end date (set the time to 11 PM)
ZonedDateTime to = LocalDate.parse("2017-07-08").atTime(23, 0).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

If the dates are in another format, you can use a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse them:

```
// parse date in day/month/year format
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
ZonedDateTime from = LocalDate.parse("05/07/2017", fmt).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Then you get the respective timestamps from each date. But as we are ignoring the seconds, I also use `truncatedTo` method to set the seconds to zero. I also divide by 1000 because your timestamps are in seconds, but the API returns it in milliseconds:

```
// get start and end timestamps
long start = from.toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli() / 1000;
long end = to.toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli() / 1000;
```

Now you traverse through your folder and check if the timestamp in the file name is between `start` and `end` - taking care of getting rid of the extra second (truncate all to zero):

```
// open directory that contains the files
File dir = new File("/your/folder/name");

// get the files with the timestamps between start and end
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        // extract number from file name
        if (name.startsWith("Product.txt.")) {
            // divide by 10 to eliminate extra second (value is rounded as it's an int)
            // then multiply by 10 again to get timestamp of respective hour
            int timestamp = (Integer.parseInt(name.replace("Product.txt.", "")) / 10) * 10;
            System.out.println(timestamp);
            return start <= timestamp && timestamp <= end;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Now you have a `files` array with all the files you need.

---

If instead of UTC you want the dates in a specific timezone, you can use the `ZoneId` class:

```
// timezone
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Baghdad");
```

And replace `ZoneOffset.UTC` by the `zone` variable above.

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

Comment: Hi @Hugo, That what search for, Thanks for the explanation and the great solution!