# How do I add one day to a Calendar object and also account for daylight savings time?

Tags: java, date, datetime, dst

I am trying to create a time limit for objects in a list. This could mean that the objects shelf life could be 23, 24 or 25 hours. Are there any Java libraries that could be useful? This is what I have so far.

My problem is that when I create a record at 9:30 am for example, it must be removed at 9:30 am on the following day. I get discrepancies when it is during the days which DST takes effect. The record is is either deleted at 8:30 or 10:30 depending if I spring forward or backward.

```
//baseValue = object that I want to check

Date dt = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(dt); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

if(baseValue.getTime() < c.getTime()){
    array.remove(baseValue);
}
```

Comment: This post needs to have some code that you've tried, or at a minimum some code setup for the problem.

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: If you are using java 8 I recommend to use the new Temporal framework (i.e. ZonedDateTime), which offers all you need.

Comment: Does your code do the job? If not, what precisely is the difference between desired and observed behaviour?

Comment: I don't really get what you want. "On the following day" and "at the same time" seem to me to contradict each other. Please edit your question and explain.

Comment: hi, I have updated the question. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), including difficulty to deal with DST changes, and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the **package names** (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

---

To take care of DST changes, the ideal class is `ZonedDateTime`, which represents a date and time in a specific timezone. I also use the `ZoneId` class, which represents the timezone itself.

I'm using my timezone (`America/Sao_Paulo`), because here we have DST as well, but you can replace with yours (more on that below):

```
// create a date 1 day before DST change in Sao Paulo, at 9 AM
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 10, 14, 9, 0, 0, 0, zone);

// get the next day, at 9 AM
ZonedDateTime nextDay = z.plusDays(1);

System.out.println(z);
System.out.println(nextDay);
```

The output is:

> 2017-10-14T09:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
>   2017-10-15T09:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

Note that the offset changed from `-03:00` to `-02:00` - it's due to DST starting in São Paulo timezone (clocks move forward 1 hour). But also note that the time (9 AM) was preserved correctly.

If we take the difference in hours, we can see that it's correct:

```
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(z, nextDay));
```

The output is:

> 23

Which correctly means that 23 hours has passed between those 2 dates (because of clocks shifting 1 hour forward, so 1 hour is "lost").

---

In your case, you need to know if 1 day has already passed, so you just call:

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(z, nextDay);
```

In this case, `days` will be 1 (even if the difference in hours calculated above is 23, because the API is smart enough to consider DST effects).

So in your case, you just need to check if the difference in days is 1 (or greater than 1, I don't know) and do all that it needs to be done.

If you need to get the current date/time, you can call `ZonedDateTime.now(zone)`.

---

To use your timezone instead of mine, first note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of timezones names with `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` - then choose the one that fits best to your case.

You can also use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` - it returns the system's default timezone. But this can be changed without notice - even at runtime - so it's recommended to use an explicit timezone.

Comment: @CalvinRaveenthran You're welcome. If you found the answer useful and it solved your problem, you can accept and/or upvote it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I dont have enough reputation as I just joined. But when I do i will definitely revisit.

Comment: @CalvinRaveenthran Actually you can accept it because it's your question. By default, all users can accept their own questions, regardless of how many reputation they have: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work (actually, the user who asked the question is the only one who can accept it).