# How do I set the date to the current day in Korea or anywhere else?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

So, I got the time to be in Korean time with this code:

```
formatClock = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
formatClock.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
```

However, how do I set the date to the current day in Korean?

For instance, I want it to output `Sunday 7/23/2017`.

Comment: You are using troublesome old classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See the [correct Answer by Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261147/642706) showing the `LocalDate` class.

Comment: @hello111 - did you get chance to check my solution?

Comment: Just seen it. But I need a couple more reps to up it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Old API

Use another `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format, and use `java.util.Locale` to explicity uses the English names for days of the week:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE M/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

The output will be:

> Sunday 7/23/2017

If you don't specify the locale, it uses the system's default, which is not guaranteed to always be English (and it can also be changed without notice, **even at runtime**, so it's always better to make it explicit in your code by using a proper `Locale`, if you always want the days of the week in English - or in any other language).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the **package names** (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To get the current date in a timezone, you can use a `LocalDate` (a date with day/month/year) with a `ZoneId` (a timezone), and you use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format it:

```
// Korean timezone
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul");
// current date in Korea timezone
LocalDate currentDateInKorea = LocalDate.now(zone);
// formatter (use English locale to correctly use English name for day of week)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE M/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(fmt.format(currentDateInKorea));
```

The output will be:

> Sunday 7/23/2017

---

Note: a `java.util.Date` itself [has no format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), it just represents the number of milliseconds since epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`). What we're doing here is just changing the **representation** of this value in a specific format, for a specific timezone.

Comment: Very nice! I got it to work. Is there a way to put a line that said "Time in Korea: "

Comment: `System.out.println("Time in Korea: " + fmt.format(currentDateInKorea));`. If this was what you meant.

Comment: Hmm I'm actually putting this into a JFrame.

Comment: That sounds like a different question if you cannot solve it from your Swing text book or tutorial. I am thinking a `JLabel`.

Comment: @hello111 If you found the answer useful and it solved your problem, please consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

suppose you should try like this.

This should display 'Sun 7/23/2017':

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
```

This should display 'Sunday 7/23/2017':

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Comment: FYI, these are legacy classes, now supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want leading zero in month then use `MM` else use `M`.

`NOTE:` View all valid time zones by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Time {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Day month/date/year
        SimpleDateFormat formatClock = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MM/dd/yyyy");
        formatClock.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
        System.out.println(formatClock.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println();
        // FYI You can check Available TimeZones as follows
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()));
    }
}
```

Sample Run

```
Sunday 07/23/2017

[Etc/GMT+12, Etc/GMT+11, Pacific/Midway, Pacific/Niue, Pacific/Pago_Pago, Pacific/Samoa, US/Samoa, America/Adak, America/Atka, Etc/GMT+10, HST, Pacific/Honolulu, Pacific/Johnston, Pacific/Rarotonga, Pacific/Tahiti, SystemV/HST10, US/Aleutian, US/Hawaii, Pacific/Marquesas, AST, America/Anchorage, America/Juneau, America/Nome, America/Sitka, America/Yakutat, Etc/GMT+9, Pacific/Gambier, SystemV/YST9, SystemV/YST9YDT, US/Alaska, America/Dawson, America/Ensenada, America/Los_Angeles, America/Metlakatla, America/Santa_Isabel, America/Tijuana, America/Vancouver, America/Whitehorse, Canada/Pacific, Canada/Yukon, Etc/GMT+8, Mexico/BajaNorte, PST, PST8PDT, Pacific/Pitcairn, SystemV/PST8, SystemV/PST8PDT, US/Pacific, US/Pacific-New, America/Boise, America/Cambridge_Bay, America/Chihuahua, America/Creston, America/Dawson_Creek, America/Denver, America/Edmonton, America/Hermosillo, America/Inuvik, America/Mazatlan, America/Ojinaga, America/Phoenix, America/Shiprock, America/Yellowknife, Canada/Mountain, Etc/GMT+7, MST, MST7MDT, Mexico/BajaSur, Navajo, PNT, SystemV/MST7, SystemV/MST7MDT, US/Arizona, US/Mountain, America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Belize, America/Cancun, America/Chicago, America/Costa_Rica, America/El_Salvador, America/Guatemala, America/Indiana/Knox, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Knox_IN, America/Managua, America/Matamoros, America/Menominee, America/Merida, America/Mexico_City, America/Monterrey, America/North_Dakota/Beulah, America/North_Dakota/Center, America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, America/Rainy_River, America/Rankin_Inlet, America/Regina, America/Resolute, America/Swift_Current, America/Tegucigalpa, America/Winnipeg, CST, CST6CDT, Canada/Central, Canada/East-Saskatchewan, Canada/Saskatchewan, Chile/EasterIsland, Etc/GMT+6, Mexico/General, Pacific/Easter, Pacific/Galapagos, SystemV/CST6, SystemV/CST6CDT, US/Central, US/Indiana-Starke, America/Atikokan, America/Bogota, America/Cayman, America/Coral_Harbour, America/Detroit, America/Fort_Wayne, America/Grand_Turk, America/Guayaquil, America/Havana, America/Indiana/Indianapolis, America/Indiana/Marengo, America/Indiana/Petersburg, America/Indiana/Vevay, America/Indiana/Vincennes, America/Indiana/Winamac, America/Indianapolis, America/Iqaluit, America/Jamaica, America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Kentucky/Monticello, America/Lima, America/Louisville, America/Montreal, America/Nassau, America/New_York, America/Nipigon, America/Panama, America/Pangnirtung, America/Port-au-Prince, America/Thunder_Bay, America/Toronto, Canada/Eastern, Cuba, EST, EST5EDT, Etc/GMT+5, IET, Jamaica, SystemV/EST5, SystemV/EST5EDT, US/East-Indiana, US/Eastern, US/Michigan, America/Caracas, America/Anguilla, America/Antigua, America/Argentina/San_Luis, America/Aruba, America/Asuncion, America/Barbados, America/Blanc-Sablon, America/Boa_Vista, America/Campo_Grande, America/Cuiaba, America/Curacao, America/Dominica, America/Eirunepe, America/Glace_Bay, America/Goose_Bay, America/Grenada, America/Guadeloupe, America/Guyana, America/Halifax, America/Kralendijk, America/La_Paz, America/Lower_Princes, America/Manaus, America/Marigot, America/Martinique, America/Moncton, America/Montserrat, America/Port_of_Spain, America/Porto_Acre, America/Porto_Velho, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Rio_Branco, America/Santiago, America/Santo_Domingo, America/St_Barthelemy, America/St_Kitts, America/St_Lucia, America/St_Thomas, America/St_Vincent, America/Thule, America/Tortola, America/Virgin, Antarctica/Palmer, Atlantic/Bermuda, Brazil/Acre, Brazil/West, Canada/Atlantic, Chile/Continental, Etc/GMT+4, PRT, SystemV/AST4, SystemV/AST4ADT, America/St_Johns, CNT, Canada/Newfoundland, AGT, America/Araguaina, America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires, America/Argentina/Catamarca, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, America/Argentina/Cordoba, America/Argentina/Jujuy, America/Argentina/La_Rioja, America/Argentina/Mendoza, America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos, America/Argentina/Salta, America/Argentina/San_Juan, America/Argentina/Tucuman, America/Argentina/Ushuaia, America/Bahia, America/Belem, America/Buenos_Aires, America/Catamarca, America/Cayenne, America/Cordoba, America/Fortaleza, America/Godthab, America/Jujuy, America/Maceio, America/Mendoza, America/Miquelon, America/Montevideo, America/Paramaribo, America/Recife, America/Rosario, America/Santarem, America/Sao_Paulo, Antarctica/Rothera, Atlantic/Stanley, BET, Brazil/East, Etc/GMT+3, America/Noronha, Atlantic/South_Georgia, Brazil/DeNoronha, Etc/GMT+2, America/Scoresbysund, Atlantic/Azores, Atlantic/Cape_Verde, Etc/GMT+1, Africa/Abidjan, Africa/Accra, Africa/Bamako, Africa/Banjul, Africa/Bissau, Africa/Casablanca, Africa/Conakry, Africa/Dakar, Africa/El_Aaiun, Africa/Freetown, Africa/Lome, Africa/Monrovia, Africa/Nouakchott, Africa/Ouagadougou, Africa/Sao_Tome, Africa/Timbuktu, America/Danmarkshavn, Atlantic/Canary, Atlantic/Faeroe, Atlantic/Faroe, Atlantic/Madeira, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Atlantic/St_Helena, Eire, Etc/GMT, Etc/GMT+0, Etc/GMT-0, Etc/GMT0, Etc/Greenwich, Etc/UCT, Etc/UTC, Etc/Universal, Etc/Zulu, Europe/Belfast, Europe/Dublin, Europe/Guernsey, Europe/Isle_of_Man, Europe/Jersey, Europe/Lisbon, Europe/London, GB, GB-Eire, GMT, GMT0, Greenwich, Iceland, Portugal, UCT, UTC, Universal, WET, Zulu, Africa/Algiers, Africa/Bangui, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Ceuta, Africa/Douala, Africa/Kinshasa, Africa/Lagos, Africa/Libreville, Africa/Luanda, Africa/Malabo, Africa/Ndjamena, Africa/Niamey, Africa/Porto-Novo, Africa/Tripoli, Africa/Tunis, Africa/Windhoek, Arctic/Longyearbyen, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, CET, ECT, Etc/GMT-1, Europe/Amsterdam, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Belgrade, Europe/Berlin, Europe/Bratislava, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Budapest, Europe/Busingen, Europe/Copenhagen, Europe/Gibraltar, Europe/Ljubljana, Europe/Luxembourg, Europe/Madrid, Europe/Malta, Europe/Monaco, Europe/Oslo, Europe/Paris, Europe/Podgorica, Europe/Prague, Europe/Rome, Europe/San_Marino, Europe/Sarajevo, Europe/Skopje, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Tirane, Europe/Vaduz, Europe/Vatican, Europe/Vienna, Europe/Warsaw, Europe/Zagreb, Europe/Zurich, Libya, MET, Poland, ART, Africa/Blantyre, Africa/Bujumbura, Africa/Cairo, Africa/Gaborone, Africa/Harare, Africa/Johannesburg, Africa/Kigali, Africa/Lubumbashi, Africa/Lusaka, Africa/Maputo, Africa/Maseru, Africa/Mbabane, Asia/Amman, Asia/Beirut, Asia/Damascus, Asia/Gaza, Asia/Hebron, Asia/Istanbul, Asia/Jerusalem, Asia/Nicosia, Asia/Tel_Aviv, CAT, EET, Egypt, Etc/GMT-2, Europe/Athens, Europe/Bucharest, Europe/Chisinau, Europe/Helsinki, Europe/Istanbul, Europe/Kiev, Europe/Mariehamn, Europe/Nicosia, Europe/Riga, Europe/Simferopol, Europe/Sofia, Europe/Tallinn, Europe/Tiraspol, Europe/Uzhgorod, Europe/Vilnius, Europe/Zaporozhye, Israel, Turkey, Africa/Addis_Ababa, Africa/Asmara, Africa/Asmera, Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, Africa/Djibouti, Africa/Juba, Africa/Kampala, Africa/Khartoum, Africa/Mogadishu, Africa/Nairobi, Antarctica/Syowa, Asia/Aden, Asia/Baghdad, Asia/Bahrain, Asia/Kuwait, Asia/Qatar, Asia/Riyadh, EAT, Etc/GMT-3, Europe/Kaliningrad, Europe/Minsk, Indian/Antananarivo, Indian/Comoro, Indian/Mayotte, Asia/Riyadh87, Asia/Riyadh88, Asia/Riyadh89, Mideast/Riyadh87, Mideast/Riyadh88, Mideast/Riyadh89, Asia/Tehran, Iran, Asia/Baku, Asia/Dubai, Asia/Muscat, Asia/Tbilisi, Asia/Yerevan, Etc/GMT-4, Europe/Moscow, Europe/Samara, Europe/Volgograd, Indian/Mahe, Indian/Mauritius, Indian/Reunion, NET, W-SU, Asia/Kabul, Antarctica/Mawson, Asia/Aqtau, Asia/Aqtobe, Asia/Ashgabat, Asia/Ashkhabad, Asia/Dushanbe, Asia/Karachi, Asia/Oral, Asia/Samarkand, Asia/Tashkent, Etc/GMT-5, Indian/Kerguelen, Indian/Maldives, PLT, Asia/Calcutta, Asia/Colombo, Asia/Kolkata, IST, Asia/Kathmandu, Asia/Katmandu, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Bishkek, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Dhaka, Asia/Qyzylorda, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Thimphu, Asia/Yekaterinburg, BST, Etc/GMT-6, Indian/Chagos, Asia/Rangoon, Indian/Cocos, Antarctica/Davis, Asia/Bangkok, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Asia/Hovd, Asia/Jakarta, Asia/Novokuznetsk, Asia/Novosibirsk, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Asia/Pontianak, Asia/Saigon, Asia/Vientiane, Etc/GMT-7, Indian/Christmas, VST, Antarctica/Casey, Asia/Brunei, Asia/Choibalsan, Asia/Chongqing, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Harbin, Asia/Hong_Kong, Asia/Kashgar, Asia/Krasnoyarsk, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Kuching, Asia/Macao, Asia/Macau, Asia/Makassar, Asia/Manila, Asia/Shanghai, Asia/Singapore, Asia/Taipei, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, Asia/Ulan_Bator, Asia/Urumqi, Australia/Perth, Australia/West, CTT, Etc/GMT-8, Hongkong, PRC, Singapore, Australia/Eucla, Asia/Dili, Asia/Irkutsk, Asia/Jayapura, Asia/Pyongyang, Asia/Seoul, Asia/Tokyo, Etc/GMT-9, JST, Japan, Pacific/Palau, ROK, ACT, Australia/Adelaide, Australia/Broken_Hill, Australia/Darwin, Australia/North, Australia/South, Australia/Yancowinna, AET, Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Asia/Khandyga, Asia/Yakutsk, Australia/ACT, Australia/Brisbane, Australia/Canberra, Australia/Currie, Australia/Hobart, Australia/Lindeman, Australia/Melbourne, Australia/NSW, Australia/Queensland, Australia/Sydney, Australia/Tasmania, Australia/Victoria, Etc/GMT-10, Pacific/Chuuk, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Port_Moresby, Pacific/Saipan, Pacific/Truk, Pacific/Yap, Australia/LHI, Australia/Lord_Howe, Antarctica/Macquarie, Asia/Sakhalin, Asia/Ust-Nera, Asia/Vladivostok, Etc/GMT-11, Pacific/Efate, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Pacific/Kosrae, Pacific/Noumea, Pacific/Pohnpei, Pacific/Ponape, SST, Pacific/Norfolk, Antarctica/McMurdo, Antarctica/South_Pole, Asia/Anadyr, Asia/Kamchatka, Asia/Magadan, Etc/GMT-12, Kwajalein, NST, NZ, Pacific/Auckland, Pacific/Fiji, Pacific/Funafuti, Pacific/Kwajalein, Pacific/Majuro, Pacific/Nauru, Pacific/Tarawa, Pacific/Wake, Pacific/Wallis, NZ-CHAT, Pacific/Chatham, Etc/GMT-13, MIT, Pacific/Apia, Pacific/Enderbury, Pacific/Fakaofo, Pacific/Tongatapu, Etc/GMT-14, Pacific/Kiritimati]
```

Comment: FYI, these are legacy classes, now supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code to do it

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd/MM/yyyy");

           // DateToStr = format.format(new Date());

            System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));

    }

}
```

Link for different formats https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/java-simpledateformat-example/

Comment: FYI, these are legacy classes, now supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.