# Android - junit - unit test - SimpleDateFormat with Timezone

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, timezone-offset

I'm using Android, JUnit and `SimpleDateFormat`.

I like to do some conversions between `String` and `Date` in rfc3339 format with timezone.

Eg: `2017-12-31T23:59:59+02:00` but not `2017-12-31T23:59:59+0200`.

Android `SimpleDateFormat` uses `Z` pattern but not `X` pattern (see `RFC3339_REGEX_1` below).

But in my JUnit test (jdk1.8), `RFC3339_REGEX_1` does not give me the right format (`+02:00`), but `+0200`. JUnit test runs well with `RFC3339_REGEX_2`.

So how can I do something clean which runs well both on Android device and JUnit test?

```
public static final String RFC3339_REGEX_1 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"; //android
public static final String RFC3339_REGEX_2 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"; //java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs. And if I'm not wrong, the `X` pattern [doesn't work in all versions](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1573#issuecomment-156911886) (I know that in [JDK 6 it wasn't supported](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it was introduced only in [JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html); not sure how this affects different Android versions).

As an alternative, in Android you can use [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). To make it work, you'll also need [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

If you still need to work with `java.util.Date`, though, this API can make things easier to you. If you want a format like `2017-12-31T23:59:59+02:00`, you can convert your `java.util.Date` to `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime` (using the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class to convert the values, and a `org.threeten.bp.ZoneOffset` to set the offset to `+02:00`):

```
// assuming that java.util.Date has value equivalent to 2017-12-31T23:59:59+02:00
Date date = ...
// convert to OffsetDateTime (use +02:00 offset)
OffsetDateTime odt = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date).atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
System.out.println(odt); // 2017-12-31T23:59:59+02:00
```

The output will be:

> 2017-12-31T23:59:59+02:00

Note that this is the result of `odt.toString()` (which is called implicity by `System.out.println`), and by default it matches the format you want. But you can also enforce a specific format, by using a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
System.out.println(fmt.format(odt));
```

The output is the same. The only difference is that the first version (using `toString()`) will print the fractions of second if they're not zero and will omit the seconds if they are zero, and the second version (with a formatter) will always print in the desired format (in this case, print the seconds but not the fraction of seconds), no matter if the values are zero or not.

I believe that, in your case, you're going to need a formatter as you seem to always need a format with seconds and without fraction of seconds.

---

To convert `OffsetDateTime` back to `Date`, you can use `DateTimeUtils` as well:

```
// convert back to java.util.Date
date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(odt.toInstant());
```

---

If you don't need to work with `java.util.Date`, you can use the `OffsetDateTime` directly:

```
// create OffsetDateTime with value = 2017-12-31T23:59:59+02:00
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(2017, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
```

Also note that I used `ZoneOffset.ofHours(2)`, which is equivalent to `ZoneOffset.of("+02:00")`.

You can also get the current date using `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2))`.

---

ThreeTen Backport is a backport for new Java 8 date/time classes, and it has  many different date and time types (like the `OffsetDateTime` above) to be used in different situations. [Check this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) for more information about what type fits best your case - the tutorial covers Java 8, but the ThreeTen Backport has the same classes and methods names, just the package is different: `org.threeten.bp` instead of `java.time`.

Comment: In Joda time we have AbstractDateTime class who provides the common behaviour for datetime classes, I did not find the correspondent in threeten (providing LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime but no abstract class)?

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai What common behavior do you need? Depending on what you need, you can use the `Temporal` or `TemporalAccessor` interfaces

Comment: I like to have something like BaseDateTime.getMillis() in Joda time and a constructor by milliseconds :)

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai I suggest you to ask another question (it seems to be the case) providing more details, specific examples, context, what have you tried, and so on. The new API differs from Jodatime in some aspects and there may be many different ways to do it, depending on your needs, and by asking another question you'll have a more precise answer.

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai But to work with milliseconds, start taking a look at the `Instant` class

Comment: Thanks you, `Instant` class is the resolution.