# Behaviour of GregorianCalendar.set() with daylight saving times

Tags: java, datetime, timezone-offset, gregorian-calendar

While troubleshooting a glitch, something strange in this method behavior appears.

---

### Context

Some countries use to save some daylight by shifting time. For example, in the timezone "Europe/Paris", each year, time shifts 1 hour forwards end March and 1 hour backwards end October, both between 2 AM and 3 AM. This causes, for example, the date October, the 30th 2016 at 02:15 AM to exist twice.

Fortunately, both dates does not have the same timestamp (ms) amount, neither readable representation :

- Before time shift : Sun Oct 30 02:15:00 CEST 2016 (+0200 from UTC)
- After time shift :  Sun Oct 30 02:15:00 CET 2016  (+0100 from UTC)

### Issue

After instantiating a `GregorianCalendar` object at the Paris timezone (using `SimpleDateFormat`), we get our 02:15 AM before backward shift as expected.

But if we want to set minutes to this object using `.set()`, the +0200 offset information gets corrupted to +0100 ("same time", but after time shift)
Is there any means of doing it this way, as the method `.add()` actually preserves the offset information?

### Example

```
    // Instantiation
    GregorianCalendar gc1 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
    gc1.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z").parse("2016-10-30 02:15:00 +0200"));
    GregorianCalendar gc2 = (GregorianCalendar) gc1.clone();
    
    System.out.println(gc1.getTime()); // Output : Sun Oct 30 02:15:00 CEST 2016 ; OK
    System.out.println(gc2.getTime()); // Output : Sun Oct 30 02:15:00 CEST 2016 ; OK
    
    // Set/add minutes
    gc1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    gc2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    
    System.out.println(gc1.getTime()); // Output : Sun Oct 30 02:10:00 CET 2016 ; Unexpected
    System.out.println(gc2.getTime()); // Output : Sun Oct 30 02:25:00 CEST 2016 ; OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ugly alternative is to subtract 1 hour from `gc1` after setting the value:

```
gc1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
gc1.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
```

The result will be `Sun Oct 30 02:10:00 CEST 2016`.

Unfortunately that seems to be the best solution available for `Calendar` API. This behaviour of `set` method was reported as a bug, and [the recommendation in JDK bug tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6615045) was to use `add` to "fix" it:

> During the "fall-back" period, Calendar doesn't support disambiguation and the given local time is interpreted as standard time.
>
> To avoid the unexpected DST to standard time change, call add() to reset the value.

I'm using Java 8, so it seems that this bug was never fixed.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only differences are:

- the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.
- conversion from/to the old `Calendar` API

To convert a `GregorianCalendar` to the new API, you can do:

```
// Paris timezone
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
// convert GregorianCalendar to ZonedDateTime
ZonedDateTime z = Instant.ofEpochMilli(gc1.getTimeInMillis()).atZone(zone);
```

In Java 8, you can also do:

```
ZonedDateTime z = gc1.toInstant().atZone(zone);
```

To get the date in the same format produced by `java.util.Date` you can use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(fmt.format(z));
```

The output is:

> Sun Oct 30 02:15:00 CEST 2016

I used a `java.util.Locale` to force the locale to English, so the month name  and day of week are formatted correclty. If you don't specify a locale, it'll use the system's default, and it's not guaranteed to always be English (and the default can also be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using).

With this API you can add or set the minutes easily:

```
// change the minutes to 10
ZonedDateTime z2 = z.withMinute(10);
System.out.println(fmt.format(z2)); // Sun Oct 30 02:10:00 CEST 2016

// add 10 minutes
ZonedDateTime z3 = z.plusMinutes(10);
System.out.println(fmt.format(z3)); // Sun Oct 30 02:25:00 CEST 2016
```

The output will be:

> Sun Oct 30 02:10:00 CEST 2016
> Sun Oct 30 02:25:00 CEST 2016

Note that in the new API, classes are immutable, so `with` and  `plus` methods return a new instance.

To convert a `ZonedDateTime` back to `GregorianCalendar`, you can do:

```
gc1.setTimeInMillis(z.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

In java 8, you can also do:

```
gc1 = GregorianCalendar.from(z);
```

---

To parse the input `2016-10-30 02:15:00 +0200`, you must use another formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XX")
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-10-30 02:15:00 +0200", parser);
```

I had to set the timezone using `withZone` method, because just the offset `+0200` is not enough to determine it ([more than one timezone can use this same offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and the API can't decide which one to use)

Comment: Fine, so this strange behavior is already well known and is an actual bug. I have actually fixed my problem with a double use of .add(), which produces the expected result. Nowadays, i am using JDK 1.7, and the API you described looks very nice, but i'm currently out of time for code refactoring (it took me an entire week to locate the issue), but i'll be right back to ZonedDateTime for any other problem.