# UTC times not matching - Java vs Moment on Node JS

Tags: android, simpledateformat, datetime-format

Using `moment.js` library on my `Node JS` server:

```
moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

I got the current time string as:

> 2017-08-02 11:57:52.616Z

On Android, I used the below code.

```
Date myDate = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.setTime(myDate);
Date time = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String dateAsString = outputFmt.format(time);
```

And the output was:

> 2017-08-02 22:58:46.163Z

How can I fix this? Difference seems to be around 11 hours.

Comment: Do you happen to be in a time zone that is 11 hours off of UTC?

Comment: India. It's +5:30

Comment: I can't really help you here, because I am not familiar with the intricacies of `Calendar` and `Date`. What I _can_ tell you is that the _reason_ I'm not familiar with them is that they are notoriously bad APIs. If you have the ability, I highly recommend using Joda Time (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), JSR-310 (http://www.threeten.org/), or Java 8's `java.time` package (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Comment: As a taste of what's so bad about `Calendar` and `Date`, I can tell you that `calendar.setTimeZone()` has no effect on the `Date` object returned by `calendar.getTime()`.

Comment: What's the result of `myDate.getTime()`?

Comment: @BenP. Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and being replaced by the new API's. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**. And I'm not sure if `java.time` is already available in Android, so in this case I guess [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp) is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **current date** in UTC, you must set the timezone on the `SimpleDateFormat`, not on the `Calendar`. And you don't need to create a `Calendar`, you can use a `Date` directly:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
outputFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateAsString = outputFmt.format(new Date()); // current date/time
```

The `X` pattern above was introduced in JDK 7, so if you are using JDK <= 6, you'll have to put a literal `Z`:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
outputFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateAsString = outputFmt.format(new Date());
```

Try with `X` first, as it's preferrable to output the correct timezone instead of a hardcoded `Z` (because if you change the timezone to another one, the `Z` will be wrong, because it's used [only when the date/time is in UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC)).

---

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

For Android, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. You'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to make it work (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

If you want the current date in UTC, you can use the `org.threeten.bp.Instant` class (which represents an UTC instant):

```
String dateAsString = Instant.now().toString();
```

The `dateAsString` variable will have a value like `2017-08-02T19:21:22.271Z`.

---

If you are working just with UTC values, the `Instant` class is enough. But if you want to work with another timezones, you must use a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime`:

```
// current time in UTC
dateAsString = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();

// current time in another timezone
dateAsString = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toString();
```

The second case will produce a different output (such as `2017-08-03T01:05:06.631+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]`) because it's using a timezone that's not UTC. You can change it, though, by using a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
dateAsString = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).format(fmt);
```

This will result in `2017-08-03T01:06:19.131+05:30`. You can also create another formats with `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("pattern")`, replacing `pattern` by the corresponding pattern letters ([check the javadoc](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern(java.lang.String)) for more details).

Note that he API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `IST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use the system's default timezone with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but this can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to explicity use a specific one.