# OffsetDateTime to Date Android

Tags: android, date, parsing

I am getting an `OffsetDateTime` from our backend in a `String` format like this:

```
"2017-07-15T10:52:59Z"
```

I am trying to parse this `String` to a Android `Date`:

```
private SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat;
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN, Locale.getDefault());

Date newDate = null;
String dateString = notice.getCreated();

try {
    newDate = mSimpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    LogHelper.showExceptionLog(MyClass.class, e);
}
```

It always throws:

> Unparseable date: "2017-07-15T10:52:59Z"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse the `Z` (which is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC)) you must use the `X` pattern (as explained in [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)):

```
SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");

String dateString = "2017-07-15T10:52:59Z";
Date newDate = mSimpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

If you use just `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` as a pattern, `SimpleDateFormat` will use the system's default timezone and ignore the `Z`, giving incorrect results: it'll parse the date/time as 10:52 in the default timezone, which can be different to 10:52 in UTC. By using the `X` pattern, you get the correct result.

I also removed the `Locale` because this formatter is not dealing with any locale-sensitive information (like month and day of week names), so it doesn't affect the parsing in this case (and `SimpleDateFormat` already uses the default locale if you don't specify one).

**PS**: the `X` pattern was introduced in JDK 7. If you're using and older version, it won't be available. In this case, you can set the UTC as a timezone of the formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
mSimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Obviously this code is assuming that the input is always in UTC (with `Z` in the end).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

For Android, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. To make it work, you'll also need [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

As the input string is in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), you can easily parse it to a `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime`:

```
String dateString = "2017-07-15T10:52:59Z";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString);
```

You can then convert this to a `java.util.Date` easily, using the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(odt.toInstant());
```

If the input is always in UTC (always with the `Z` in the end), you can also use a `org.threeten.bp.Instant`:

```
String dateString = "2017-07-15T10:52:59Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(instant);
```

---

The only difference is that `Instant` only parses UTC inputs (ending with `Z`) and `OffsetDateTime` accepts any valid UTC offset (like `-03:00` or `+05:30`).