# How to get the data time pattern with time zone based on the locale?

Tags: java, timezone, datetime-format, java-time

The following code is what I already have:

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Java_Locale);
SimpleDateFormat sf = (SimpleDateFormat) f;
String pattern = sf.toPattern();
```

With the above code, I am able to get the PROPER date/time pattern based on the locale. For example: "M/d/yy h:mm a" for US English, "yy-M-d ah:mm" for Chinese.

However, this pattern does not have the time zone information. I hope to be able to add time zone into the pattern. For example, "M/d/yy h:mm a z" for English, but I don't want to specify the pattern for other locales. I hope to get the proper pattern with time zone based on a given locale, something similar to "M/d/yy h:mm a z" for other locales.

I use Java 8.

Comment: Are the time-zones locale-specific? Why not to just retrieve the current timezone and add to already formatted string?

Comment: Time zones can be any of of Java supports, and they are independent of locales. I am not sure simply appending the "z" to the formatted pattern string would create a new format that is proper to any given locale.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using the `java.time` classes like `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: FYI, if you don't strictly need localized formats, you might consider using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats which include the offset-from-UTC, further extended by the java.time class [`ZonedDateTime`] to append the name of the time zone in square brackets. The standard formats are generally understandable across cultures. Ex: `2017-08-22T16:30:48.399-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.FULL, Java_Locale);
```

The `FULL` time style includes the time zone. This will make the time more complex, though.

Note: just adding a `z` to the pattern string is not always accurate. For instance, Arabic language locales put the time zone between the date and time:

```
Locale Java_Locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("ar");
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.FULL, Java_Locale);
SimpleDateFormat sf = (SimpleDateFormat) f;
String pattern = sf.toPattern(); // "dd/MM/yy z hh:mm:ss a"
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean. `just adding a z to the pattern string is not always accurate.`-->this is exactly what I am concerned about.

Answer (score 4):

`z` is a valid pattern for `SimpleDateFormat` (according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it's the timezone designator) for **any** locale.

The only difference is that for some values the result might be locale dependent (example: if you use `zzzz`, the timezone `America/Los_Angeles` can be formatted as **Pacific Daylight Time** in English (as it's currently in Daylight Saving Time) or **Horário de luz natural do Pacífico** in Portuguese), but the pattern `z` itself is not invalid regardless of the locale.

And `getDateTimeInstance` will use predefined built-in hardcoded patterns. As the short patterns usually don't include the timezone, you'll have to add the `z` manually:

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat sf = (SimpleDateFormat) f;
String pattern = sf.toPattern();

// add z to the format, use the same locale
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern + " z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

As you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

Unfortunately the predefined built-in patterns are still hardcoded and you have to add the timezone manually, but at least you'll get rid of all the problems explained in the links above:

```
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

// get built-in localized format for a specified locale
String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT,
                     FormatStyle.SHORT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.ENGLISH);
// create a formatter, add the timezone manually, use same locale
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern + " z", Locale.ENGLISH);
// format a date
System.out.println(fmt.format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
```

As you're printing the timezone, I'm using a `ZonedDateTime`, which represents a date and a time in a specific timezone. Check the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for more details about the new date types.

`DateTimeFormatter` also have more options than `SimpleDateFormat`. Check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) for details.

---

If you still need interoperability with a `java.util.Date`, you can easily convert it to the new API:

```
// convert to Instant (UTC)
ZonedDateTime z = new Date().toInstant()
    // convert to some timezone
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

Comment: Hi Hugo, adding "z"  to the pattern is not always accurate, which is why I posted the question in the first place. Please see Sean's answer. Thanks SO much  for your detailed answer, which will surely help many others. Regards.

Comment: @curious1 No problem. When changing these pre-defined built-in formats, there's always a risk to mess up something. Glad you found an answer, good luck!