# Comparing Dates in Java 7 using Calendar

Tags: calendar, java-7, java-time, date-comparison

I am comparing the start Date of a treatement to its End to check if it lasts more than 6 months. If the period doesn't include the month of February all is good but if I compare the 1st of January to the 30th of June, it throws my Exception. To compare both periods I add 6 months to the start Date and compare the result to the end Date like so:

```
Date start = new Date(2017,1,1);
Date end = new Date(2017,6,30);

Calendar startOfTreatment = new Calendar.getInstance();
startOfTreatment.setTime(start);

Calendar endOfTreatment = new Calendar.getInstance();
endOfTreatment.setTime(end);

startOfTreatment.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
if (startOfTreatment.compareTo(endOfTreatment) > 0) {
    throw new InfinishedTreatmentException(startOfTreatment,endOfTreatment);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It might be worth posting a bit more code, such as how startOfTreatment is populated - is it an actual date, with a year?

Comment: I added the test I am working with

Comment: Six months after 1st of February is 1st of August, which is, in fact, later than 30th of July.  Is that not what you expected?

Comment: No even when I test with the first of July same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` constructors (like the one you're using: `new Date(2017,1,1)`) are not only **deprecated** (so you should avoid them) but also **misleading**, because years are indexed at 1900 (so 2017 becomes 3917) and months are zero-indexed (the values are in the range zero (January) to 11 (December)). So this doesn't behave as you think:

```
Date start = new Date(2017, 1, 1); // February 1st 3917
Date end = new Date(2017, 6, 30); // July 30th 3917
```

When you add 6 months to `start`, it becomes **August 1<sup>st</sup>**, which is after `end`.

To create January 1<sup>st</sup> and June 30<sup>th</sup> you must use `month - 1` and to have the year 2017 you must use 117 (2017 - 1900):

```
Date start = new Date(117, 0, 1); // January 1st 2017
Date end = new Date(117, 5, 30); // June 30th 2017
```

Even though, `start` plus 6 months will be **July 1<sup>st</sup>**, which still is after `end` (so your code will throw the exception).

---

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

In **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes.

This new API has [lots of new date and time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) to deal with different situations. As we're dealing only with dates (day/month/year), we can use a `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1); // January 1st 2017
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 30); // June 30th 2017

// 6 months after start
LocalDate sixMonthsLater = start.plusMonths(6);
if (sixMonthsLater.isAfter(end)) {
    // throw exception
}
```