# How to create a calendar with the default GMT hours in java

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, datetime-format

I'm getting a long from a server that I have to parse into a date. I'm using a calendar to do so.

Thing is that the long came transformed from the server (it have the user local time), but I get it as a default GMT and I also transform it into local time.

So, it transforms twice. Since I get it right, how can I show it without changing it to local (seems to do it by default)? My code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));           
calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateLong);
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
format1.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: To understand your question correctly, do you want the time in "GMT" or your local time (without changing it)?

Comment: @procrastinator in GMT. I get it from the server in local time, but it detects it in GMT and converts it again. So, If I show it in GMT (since is already converted) it should show it right.

Comment: It works. Thanks, post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Calendar` use `SimpleDateFormat`. the following code shows me the correct results.

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String result = df.format(dateLong);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already provide solutions with `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. I'd just like to add another approach.

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

In Android (if you're ok about adding a dependency to your project - and in this case it's totally worth it, IMO), you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. To make it work, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

First you can use a `org.threeten.bp.Instant` to convert the millis value to a corresponding UTC instant. Then you use a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter` to define the format you want the date. I also use a `org.threeten.bp.ZoneOffset` to indicate that the formatter should use the date in UTC:

```
long dateLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
// convert long millis value to Instant
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateLong);
// create formatter in UTC
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// format it
System.out.println(fmt.format(instant));
```

The output will be something like:

> 13/09/2017 11:28:02

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood
I guess you have time in milliseconds. Well, from there:

```
Date dateCreated = new Date(timeInMilliseconds);
```

And then when you create the Calendar, just set Timezone after set time, because setTimeInMillis is overriding your previous TimeZone set when you are creating the instance

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(new java.util.Date().getTime());
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

That's it

Comment: I don't understand, the string result of this is: 2017-09-13T12:44:20Z

Comment: I think I missunderstood. So, you have a Date object in milliseconds (that's why you say in Long value) and then what do you want to do? Because the Date is already created with Timezone value when you create a new Date(timeInMilliseconds)

Comment: I get the long from a server, but I think the pass it converted to the local timezone of the user. However, I get it as GMT and convert it again to local timezone of the user. So, it has 2h more than it has to. Since I get it converted from the server, how can I show it without convert it again (by default the calendar timezone is the user timezone, so it converts the date). I've tried with Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")), it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work but they gived me the answer up there. I has to change the dateFormater timezone. Thanks anyway.