# Unable to convert UTC to IST, it is still returning me UTC only

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone, datetime-parsing

I am trying to convert UTC Date to IST. But to my surprise, after converting everything, it is still returning me UTC only. How is it possible?

INPUT:

```
StartDateTimeUtc='2017-09-15T14:00:00', 
EndDateTimeUtc='2017-09-15T15:00:00'
```

Code:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";

Date meetingStartDate = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(model.StartDateTimeUtc);
Date meetingEndDate = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(model.EndDateTimeUtc);

            //Convert Date to String
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT);
            String meetinStartDateString = df.format(meetingStartDate);
            String meetingEndDateString = df.format(meetingEndDate);

            //Convert String Date to IST
            SimpleDateFormat dftwo = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT);
            dftwo.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
            Date date = null;
            Date datetwo = null;
            try {
                date = dftwo.parse(meetinStartDateString);
                datetwo = dftwo.parse(meetingEndDateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dftwo.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            String formattedStartDate = dftwo.format(date);
            String formattedEndDate = dftwo.format(datetwo);

            //Convert String Date back to Date format so that we can pass into Calendar code
            Date meetingStartDateFinal = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(formattedStartDate);
            Date meetingEndDateFinal = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMATE_CURRENT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(formattedEndDate);
```

OUTPUT again in UTC:

```
Start Date : Fri Sep 15 14:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
End Date : Fri Sep 15 15:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
```

Comment: `GMT+05:30` is not UTC. Also, if you could please **[edit]** the question and add the values of `model.StartDateTimeUtc` and `model.EndDateTimeUtc`, and also what should the the correct output. Anyway, if you're printing the `Date` objects directly, keep in mind that a date [has no timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date), and what you see is the result of `toString()` method (that uses the JVM default timezone behind the scenes).

Comment: Thanks @Hugo : I have edited and added start and end time. Thanks

Comment: The troublesome `Date` class is now replaced by the java.time classes, specifically `Instant`. Example: `Instant.now().atZone( "Asia/Kolkata" )`

Answer (score 0):

A `java.util.Date` [doesn't have any timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). It just contains one value: the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`, or January 1<sup>st</sup> 1907, at midnight in **UTC**).

This number of milliseconds is the same, everywhere in the world. What's is different is the corresponding date and time in each timezone. Example: right now, this millis value is `1505481835424`, which corresponds, in UTC, to `2017-09-15T13:23:55.424Z`. This same value corresponds to 10:23 AM in São Paulo, 18:53 in Kolkata, 14:23 in London and so on. The local date/time is different in each timezone, but the millis value is the same for everyone.

That's why you don't convert a `Date` itself: the millis value is the same, and there's no need to change it. What you can change is the **representation** of this date in different timezones.

`SimpleDateFormat`, by default, uses the JVM default timezone to parse dates. But if you know that the inputs are in a specific zone, you must set in the formatter. So, to parse your inputs, you must do:

```
String startDateTimeUtc = "2017-09-15T14:00:00";
String endDateTimeUtc = "2017-09-15T15:00:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
// input is in UTC
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

// parse dates
Date meetingStartDate = sdf.parse(startDateTimeUtc);
Date meetingEndDate = sdf.parse(endDateTimeUtc);
```

The 2 `Date` objects above will correspond to 14:00 and 15:00 UTC (which is the same as 19:30 and 20:30 in Kolkata timezone).

But if you just print the `Date` objects directly (using `System.out.println`, logging, or even checking their values in a debugger), it'll implicity call the `toString()` method, which uses the JVM default timezone behind the scenes, resulting in the output you're seeing (`Fri Sep 15 14:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017`).

If you want to print in a specific format, and in a specific timezone, you'll need another formatter:

```
// another formatter for output
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
// output will be in Asia/Kolkata timezone
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));

System.out.println(outputFormat.format(meetingStartDate));
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(meetingEndDate));
```

The output will be:

> 2017-09-15T19:30:00
>   2017-09-15T20:30:00

Which corresponds to the same UTC dates in Kolkata timezone.

Just remember: you don't convert the `Date`'s between timezones (because their millis values are "absolute" - they are the same for everyone in the world). You just change the `String` representation of those dates (the corresponding date/time in a specific timezone).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. To make it work, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

This new API has lots of different date/time types for each situation. In this case, the inputs have date and time, but no timezone information, so first I parse them to a `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime`, using a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
// parse the inputs
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
LocalDateTime startDt = LocalDateTime.parse(startDateTimeUtc, fmt);
LocalDateTime endDt = LocalDateTime.parse(endDateTimeUtc, fmt);
```

Then I use a `org.threeten.bp.ZoneOffset` to convert them to UTC, and later a `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` to convert this to another timezone. The result will be a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime`:

```
// input is in UTC
ZoneOffset utc = ZoneOffset.UTC;
// convert to Asia/Kolkata
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
ZonedDateTime start = startDt.atOffset(utc).atZoneSameInstant(zone);
ZonedDateTime end = endDt.atOffset(utc).atZoneSameInstant(zone);
```

Then I use the same `DateTimeFormatter` to format the output:

```
System.out.println(fmt.format(start));
System.out.println(fmt.format(end));
```

The output is:

> 2017-09-15T19:30:00
>   2017-09-15T20:30:00

Note that I don't need to set the timezone in the formatter, because the timezone information is in the objects (they are responsible to do the conversion).