# Formatting ISO 8601 in Java 7

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I have date format like this `2016-11-25T09:29:10.588+01:00`

I want to convert this to `milliseconds` and later while printing I have to again convert milliseconds to "`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`" this format.

```
static FastDateFormat alarmDateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String string1 = "2016-11-25T09:29:10.588+01:00";
Date result1 = df1.parse(string1);
long timeStamp = result1.getTime();
System.out.println("timeStamp : " +timeStamp);
String eventTime = alarmDateFormat.format(timeStamp);
System.out.println("AfterConverting : " + eventTime);
```

Result :

```
timeStamp : 1480062550588
AfterConverting : 2016-11-25 13:59:10.588
```

`Date` is proper but the time is different. I have tried setting timezone to "UTC" but it did't help.

Please note: In Java 8 it works fine with other libraries like Instant and all but we wanted in Java 7.

Comment: "i have tried setting timezone also "UTC" but it did't help" - well it should... if you set the time zone for `FastDateFormat`, that is. Please show how you've tried to set the time zone.

Comment: df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Comment: @HarshaG Always update (you can edit) your question with new informations.

Comment: What should be the output? 09:29?

Comment: @Hugo Yes when we convert back  it should give original time 09:29

Comment: Well that's setting the time zone in the wrong formatter...

Comment: “In Java 8 it works fine with other libraries like Instant and all but we wanted in Java 7.” So why not just use [**ThreeTen Backport**](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)? It offers the modern Java date and time API, with `Instant` and all, in Java 6 and 7.

Comment: Yes, you *really* should add ThreeTen-Backport to your project. The old legacy date-time classes are a wretched mess, confusing, badly-designed.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `setTimeZone` in `df1`, but this formatter is used only for parsing, and it won't have any effect in formatting.

To format the date to a specific timezone, you must set it in the other formatter (if you don't set, the formatter uses the JVM default timezone). Also, you don't need to rely on another class such as `FastDateFormat`, you can simply use another `SimpleDateFormat`.

But to get exactly the same date/time, you need to use the same offset used in the input (`+01:00`). `Date` objects [don't keep this information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), so you must extract it from the input. One way would be to use `substring`:

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
String string1 = "2016-11-25T09:29:10.588+01:00";
Date result1 = df1.parse(string1);
long timeStamp = result1.getTime();
System.out.println("timeStamp : " + timeStamp);

// extract the +01:00 offset from the input
String offset = string1.substring(23);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
// set the offset in the formatter (so output is converted to it)
df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + offset));
String eventTime = df2.format(timeStamp);
System.out.println("AfterConverting : " + eventTime);
```

The output will be:

> timeStamp : 1480062550588
>   AfterConverting : 2016-11-25 09:29:10.588

If you want to keep using `FastDateFormat`, it's also possible to set the timezone in it:

```
FastDateFormat f = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + offset));
String eventTime = f.format(timeStamp);
```

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

For **Java 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

With this, you can parse the input to a `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime` and use a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter` for the output. In this case, the `OffsetDateTime` keeps the offset information, so you don't need to set it in the formatter:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(string1);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println("timeStamp : " + odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
System.out.println("AfterConverting : " + odt.format(fmt));
```

The output is the same:

> timeStamp : 1480062550588
>   AfterConverting : 2016-11-25 09:29:10.588