# How to format date/time in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-07:00

Tags: android, date, timezone, formatter

I am having a difficult time formatting the date/time to include "-07:00" as the time zone. An ideal example is "2018-06-19T14:45:10-07:00".

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        String dateTime = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

The result of this is something like

> "2018-06-19T14:45:10"

. I want to have -07:00 at the end of it. I have also tried to change the formatter to include the timezone

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
```

The result of this is something like

> "2018-06-19T14:45:10Z"

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting ISO 8601 in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300515/formatting-iso-8601-in-java-7)

Comment: Consider throwing the classes `Calendar`, `TimeZone` and `SimpleDateFormat` away. They are long outmoded and poorly designed and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead you may add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V. ThreeTenABP works better in your opinion? How is it for formatting though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the quotes around `Z`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());// 2018-06-19T22:38:28+0000
```

Comment: Ok, let me try that. Thanks!