# Retrieve Sunday from a specific date

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek

I am trying to create a function where I will send a specific date (e.g. `2017-09-16` and it will return the Sunday of this week.

For instance, if I send `2017-09-16` it must return `2017-09-17`.

I was trying to do it using Calendar.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

And this will return me the day of the week but I do not exactly know how to the convert it to Sunday.

Comment: First you need to define what's the first day of the week, as it's [not the same in all countries](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days). If you use ISO definition (Monday is the first day of week), then 2017-09-17 is the right answer. But in US, the first day of week is Sunday, so the Sunday in the same week of 2017-09-16 is 2017-09-10.
Or do you just want "the next Sunday" regardless of week-definitions?

Comment: FYI, the code in this Question uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider avoiding `Calendar` and using better API's suited for date manipulation. The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java 6 or 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

First you need to define what's the first day of the week, as [it's not the same in all countries](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/). You can use ISO's definition (Monday is the first day of the week), so your code will be like this:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, 9, 16);
// use ISO definition (Monday is the first day of week)
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.ISO;
LocalDate sundayInSameWeek = date
    // get the first day of this week
    .with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1)
    // get next Sunday (or the same date, if it's already Sunday)
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
System.out.println(sundayInSameWeek); // 2017-09-17
```

The result is `2017-09-17`. But if I use a different definition of week (such as US's definition, where Sunday is the first day of the week):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, 9, 16);
// use US's definition of week (Sunday is the first day of week)
WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate sundayInSameWeek = date ... // all the same code
```

The result will be `2017-09-10`, because in US, Sunday is the first day of week, so the *"Sunday in the same week as 2017-09-17"* is indeed `2017-09-10`.

---

If you just want **the next Sunday**, regardless of week definitions, you can just use the `TemporalAdjusters` class:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, 9, 16);
LocalDate nextSunday = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)); // 2017-09-17
```

---

If you have a `String` with the date, you can parse it directly to a `LocalDate`:

```
// creates 2017-09-16
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2017-09-16");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was just what I wanted in order to understand completely the Date thing. Great response!

Comment: @JustCodingPlease You're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

To find the *next* Sunday, use Java 8 [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and either [`TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-) or [`TemporalAdjusters.next(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-).

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2017-09-16");
date = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
System.out.println(date); // prints: 2017-09-17
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LocalDate` which is the Java 8 API for `date` 
(`LocalTime` for `time` and `LocalDateTime` for both)

---

You have juste to add the number of days missing between your date an d next sunday, which correponds to `7-dayOfWeek` :

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, 9, 16);
LocalDate sundayNext = date.plusDays(7 - date.getDayOfWeek().getValue());
```

---

If you are `Monday` , `dayOfWeek` is 1 and you next `sunday` is in `(7-1) = 6 days`

If you are `Tuesday`, `dayOfWeek` is 2 and you next `sunday` is in `(7-2) = 5 days`

**...**

Comment: `LocalDate` is not the API for date and *time*. It very specifically is date *only*.

Answer (score 1):

In your case where Sunday is last day of week, you can subtract current day of week from 7, and add result to date.

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(2017, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 16);
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7 - (date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1));

System.out.println(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));    // prints "17"
```

But I recommend to use Java 8 new API for date [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) as suggested in [Hugo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349009/7427240) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date yourDate = sm.parse("2017-09-16");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(yourDate);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    System.out.println(day);
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, 8 - dayOfWeek + day);
    Date nextSunDate = c.getTime();

    System.out.println(yourDate);     //2017-09-16
    System.out.println(nextSunDate);  //2017-09-17 
}
```

If your date is `2017-09-17` then `nextSunDate` will be `2017-09-24`

Comment: This Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.