# Android converting the time in milliseconds

Tags: java, android, time, datetime-format, milliseconds

I have checked questions about converting time in milliseconds and I followed all answers, but I am still getting the wrong number of hours, although the minutes and seconds are ok.

In my application the user has to select a time from a `TimePickerDialog` and set the time in the textview. It will show for example `01:30` in a clock. It will show me `502125000222:30:00`

My code `TimePickerDialog`:

```
 TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        Calendar mycalendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
        mycalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        mycalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        mycalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        long times = mycalendar.getTimeInMillis();

         //  hmsTimeFormatter is a method return time format
        String timerRemaind =  hmsTimeFormatter(times);

             //tv_remaindertime is TextView 

           tv_remaindertime.setText(timerRemaind); 
          ............
```

And this `hmsTimeFormatter` method that converts milliseconds:

```
private String hmsTimeFormatter(long milliSeconds) {

    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliSeconds),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliSeconds)),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSeconds) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds)));

    return hms;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's happening:

- `Calendar.getInstance()` creates a `Calendar` with the current date/time in the JVM default timezone
- You set the hour, minutes and seconds (to `01:30:00` I suppose)
- You call `getTimeInMillis()`, that returns the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`)

Then you use this milliseconds value with `TimeUnit`, but that's not what you need. `TimeUnit` will treat the number of milliseconds as an **amount of time**, but what you need is a **time of the day**:

- a **time of the day** is a specific moment in a day, such as *"10 AM"* or *"05:30 PM"*.
- an **amount of time** is just, well, an amount of elapsed time, such as *"10 minutes and 45 seconds"*, or *"2 years, 4 months, 5 days and 17 hours"*, but it's not attached to a specific point in time ("10 minutes relative to what?"); it's just the amount of time, by itself.

*Although both concepts might use the same words ("hours", "minutes", "seconds", etc), they're not the same thing.*

`TimeUnit` deals with amounts of time, so it does conversions like *"1000 seconds is equivalent to how many minutes?"*.
Example: `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(value)` returns the **number of hours** equivalent to `value` milliseconds (not the time of the day). As the value you're using is the result of `getTimeInMillis()`, you're getting the total number of hours since January 1970.

By using the result of `getTimeInMillis()` (which represents a specific point in time) with `TimeUnit`, you're misusing the value, treating like it was an amount of time.

To format a date, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Calendar mycalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mycalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
mycalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
mycalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// format: hour:minute:second
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String hms = sdf.format(mycalendar.getTime()); // 01:30:00
```

With this, `hms` will have the value `01:30:00`. [Check the javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to know what the format `HH:mm:ss` means, so you can change it in case you need a different format (If you want just `01:30`, for example, the format will be `HH:mm`).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. To make it work, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

First you create a `org.threeten.bp.LocalTime` (a class that represents a time of the day), then you format it with a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
// create time for 01:30
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(1, 30);
// format: hour:minute:second
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String hms = fmt.format(time);
System.out.println(hms); // 01:30:00
```

Also, [check the javadoc](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern(java.lang.String)) for all available formats.

Answer (score 0):

Hello how about using a powerful Library? its very easy and useful,
it`s saves you from many line
[Joda-Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time)

Usage :
Gradle configuration:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
```

for more information and documentation :

https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Happy Coding!

Comment: I dont need libaray  because it something that  not need that much

Comment: Although a great API (I used a lot and really enjoy it), Joda-Time is now in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**. In Android there's the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8 new date/time API

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to have millis converted to HH:mm:ss.
For that we use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
private String hmsTimeFormatter(long milliSeconds) {

    Date date = new Date(milliSeconds);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return format.format(date);
}
```

Just Try it and change the format Syntax to the one you like