# How to recognize a datetime format?

Tags: java, scala, date, datetime

Datetime objects come to my program in two different formats: as unix timestamps and as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`. For example, `1520877600` or `2018-04-23 11:12:00.0`. I need to extract a year and month from these objects, automatically recognizing a format.

This is the function that extracts `year` from `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`:

```
  def getYear(datetimeString: Any): Int = {
    var year = 2017
    if (!datetimeString.toString.isEmpty) {
      val dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
      val dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)
      val d = java.time.LocalDate.parse(datetimeString.toString, dtf)
      year = d.getYear
    }
    year
  }
```

And this is the same function for the unix timestamp:

```
  def getYear(timestamp: Any): Int = {
    var year = 2017
    if (!timestamp.toString.isEmpty)
    {
      year = new DateTime(timestamp.toString.toLong).getYear
    }
    year
  }
```

How can I merge them into a single function, so that my program would be flexible and would work with both formats?

Comment: Use one format, if that fails, use the other

Comment: Conceptually, consider creating a new wrapper function which takes in a variable `timestampOrDatetime`. Check to see if the variable is all digits, if it is, use your timestamp code. If not, use your datetime code.

Comment: @jwriteclub: Good idea, thanks. I came out with this solution `def isAllDigits(x: String) = x forall Character.isDigit`.

Comment: @ScalaBoy great. You know you can go ahead and answer your own question so that the knowledge is more easily accessible for anyone who comes across it in the future.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should consider isolating usage of auto-detection code to the edges of your system - internally it's best to store data in structures where the type is known, in a consistent form, or with metadata about the type. Auto-detection can be a bug breeding ground as when it goes wrong, it can be hard to notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to build a formatter with optional parts, where each optional part is a `DateTimeFormatter` that can parse one of those formats.

I'm posting code in Java, because I'm not a Scala dev, but it shouldn't be hard to adapt it.

First you make the formatter for the date/time pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter datetimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

Then you make another formatter to parse the timestamp. The value `1520877600` seems to be in **seconds since unix epoch**, so you can use the [`ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#INSTANT_SECONDS) field:

```
DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // parse timestamp value in seconds
    .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

And then you join the 2 formatters above in a single one, making each formatter optional:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .appendOptional(datetimeFormatter)
    // timestamp
    .appendOptional(timestampFormatter)
    // use JVM default timezone
    .toFormatter().withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Another detail is the `withZone` method to set a timezone to be used by the formatter. That's because an unix timestamp represents a count of elapsed time since unix epoch, and the value 1520877600 can represent a different date and time, depending on the timezone you are.

I'm using the JVM default timezone (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`), but you can choose it to whatever you need. Exampe: if I use `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")`, the timestamp will be converted to New York timezone. Using a different timezone can affect the values of year and month, specially if the value corresponds to the first or last day of the month (and if I don't set a timezone, the parsing will fail for timestamps, because it needs a timezone to "translate" the timestamp to a date/time).

Anyway, as you want the year and month values, the best choice is to parse directly to a [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), which in turn can be used to get the correspondent `int` values for year and month:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse("2018-04-23 11:12:00.0", fmt);
int year = ym.getYear();
int month = ym.getMonthValue();

ym = YearMonth.parse("1520877600", fmt);
year = ym.getYear();
month = ym.getMonthValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  val isoFormat = "(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2})\\:(\\d{2})\\:(\\d{2})\\.(\\d+)".r 

  def getYear(timestamp: Any): Int = timestamp match {
      case isoFormat(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millis) => year.toInt
      case l : Long => {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        c.setTimeInMillis(l)
        c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
      }
      case _ => 2017
  }

  println(getYear("2018-03-31 14:12:00.231"))
  println(getYear(System.currentTimeMillis()))
  println(getYear("Foo"))
```

This example uses scala's pattern matching syntax. Let's start from the bottom:

- If the given value is neither a proper string of a long, return 2017 as default (might want to make this configurable)
- If the value is a long, parse it - I used Calendar in this case to avoid the string conversions, you may want to add your time zone
- If the code is a iso formatted string, use a regex to extract the fields we want. This may seem like compiler magic at first, but is simply using scala's unapply method for pattern matching. You can find a proper explanation here: [REGULAR EXPRESSION PATTERNS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/regular-expression-patterns.html) . Note: This could be written shorter, verbose version for clarity.

The main benefit I see with the above approach is that it will be very straight-forward to extends the method with additional date formats.

Comment: I'm a big fan of regex, but in this case I wouldn't use it because, although it might seem good for parsing a date, it's bad for validating it. Inputs like `9999-99-99 99:99:99.999` will be considered valid by the regex, while a proper class such as `DateTimeFormatter` will correctly throw an exception. Not to mention the tons of corner cases (day > 31, day zero, February 29th in a non-leap year, etc). I know the question is about "getting year from a date-like string", but I think that the input must be validated as being a correct date/time value, and regex is not the best tool for it

Answer (score 1):

This code takes your inputs and gets the year. It uses SimpleDateFormat to convert.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Calendar, Date, GregorianCalendar}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

def recognizeTimeStamp(timeStamp: String): Int = {

  val myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
  timeStamp match {
    case "unknown" => -1
    case x if x.replaceAll("\\d", "") == "" => {
      myCal.setTime(new Date(x.toLong))
      myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    }

    case x =>
       val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
       Try(format.parse(x)) match {
            case Success(t) => {
                myCal.setTime(t)
                myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            }
            case Failure(_) => -1
       }
   }
}

recognizeTimeStamp("2018-04-23 11:12:00.0")
recognizeTimeStamp("1334946600000")
```

Answer from my Scala worksheet:

```
res0: Int = 2018
res1: Int = 2012
```

Comment: OP is using [`java.time` classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime), which is a most modern and [much better](https://madhuraoakblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/08/performance-improvement-with-date-time-api-of-java-8/) API than `SimpleDateFormat`. This class (and also `Date` and `Calendar`) has [tons of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265) and [bad-design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442), and using `java.time` is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution suggested in comments. I created a function `def isAllDigits(x: String) = x forall Character.isDigit` and check if the String is all digits or not.